# Run a command in a shell and keep running the command when you close the session

Tags: linux, shell, command

I am using Putty to connect to a remote server. What I want to know is if there is any way to write my commands and allow them to keep running after I close the session with Putty. The reason for this is that I do not want to keep the computer ON all the time. Is there any way to do this?.

**Update with the solution**

For my question as it is presented the best solution is use one of the commands provided such as **nohup**, because you do not have to install any additional software. But if you are in the same problem use screen, install it and use it. It is amazing.

I have selected the answer of Norman Ramsey as favourite because propose several solutions using commands and **screen**. But please check the other answers specially the one of PEZ, then you get an insight of what screen is able todo.

Comment: Duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Linux, how to prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285015/608639), [How to make a program continue to run after log out from ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/954302/608639), etc.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`nohup`, `disown`, and `screen` are all good but `screen` is the best because unlike the other two, `screen` allows you to disconnect from the remote server, keep everything running, and then reconnect later to see what is happening.  With `nohup` and `disown` you can't resume interacting.

Answer (score 91):

**screen!** It's the best thing since sliced bread. (Yeah, I know others have already suggested it, but it's so good the whole world should join in and suggest it too.)

screen is like, like, ummmm ... like using VNC or the like to connect to a GUI destop, but for command shell windows. You can have several shell "windows" open at once in the same screen session. You can do stuff like:

1. Start a screens session using "screen -dR" (get used to using -dR)

   - run some commands in one window
   - press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd> to create a new window open a file there in vim
   - press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd> to go back to the first window and issue some command on the file you just edited
   - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> to go back to your vim session
   - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> for yet another window and maybe do "sudo - su" (because you just happen to need a full root shell)
   - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> and start a background process
   - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> to create yet a new window, "tail -f" the log for that background process
   - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> to disconnect your screen then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to disconnect from the server
   - Go on vacation for three weeks
   - Log on to the server again and issue "screen -dR" to connect to your existing screen session
   - check the log in the the fourth window with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> (it's like you've been there watching it all the time)
   - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> to pick up that vim session again
   - I guess you're starting to get the picture now? =)

It's like magic. I've been using screen for longer than I can remember and I'm still totally amazed with how bloody great it is.

**EDIT**: Just want to mention there's now also **tmux**. Very much like **screen**, but has some unique features, splitting the windows being the most prominent one.

Comment: I start/join my screen session with `screen -xRR`.

Comment: J.F. pretend I'm lazy and don't want to do "man screen". Can you tell us why -xRR?

Comment: I agree. Screen rules. But isn't the default command key "CTRL-a", which means that your examples above wouldn't work for a new user?

Comment: Thanks. I got carried away. =) Now fixed.

Comment: You can split windows in `screen` too.

Answer (score 10):

Try using [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).  It allows you to have several shells open at once.  And you can disconnect from those running shells (i.e. close session with Putty) and they will keep doing their thing.

Comment: Screen is also nice because it will handle both accidental and purposeful disconnections.  I use it anytime I'm working with flaky connectivity.

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking for is [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

See the wiki link for how to use it.

Answer (score 6):

`screen` is the best.

Try:

```
screen -dmS "MyTail" tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

This start command in background.

Use `screen -r` to list, and or `screen -r` Mytail to enter session.

If more users need access same session, use:  screen -rx MyTail, and both or more users share the session.

Comment: Is there a way to do this where the screen session will not end because the program does?

Answer (score 4):

If you can't use `screen` (because, for instance, your SSH session is being programmatically driven), you can also use [daemonize](http://www.clapper.org/software/daemonize/) to run the program as a daemon.

Answer (score 4):

One way that works well for me is `at`.

`at` works like cron, but for a one-time job.  I used it today to download a large file without having to keep my session alive.

for example:

```
$ at 23:55
at> wget http://file.to.download.com/bigfile.iso
at> ^D
```

You pass `at` a time (in the future) and it gives you a prompt.  You enter the commands you want to run at that time and hit ctrl+d.  You can exit out of your session and it will run the commands at the specified time.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix_command%29) has more info on `at`.

Answer (score 1):

```
./command & disown
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh localhost && ./command && exit
```

Comment: If you are going to answer a 5 year old question that already has 8 other answers, you should really try to make it a very good answer, with explanation... not just a one-liner.

Comment: Ah ok, I did not realize that question was too old :/