# How to make a program continue to run after log out from ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client)

I have a program that takes a lot of time to finish.
It is running as root over ssh.
I want it to continue to run after I logout,is this possible and how would I achieve this?

Comment: The nohup(1) idea is better than disown IMHO because disown is a shell-specific built-in of BASH while nohup is part of coreutils and likely to be everywhere.

Comment: Use `batch`, e.g. `echo myprogram its arguments | batch`

Comment: Here's how you can do it *after* it has started. You'll need to install `reptyr` and `screen`. Start a screen session by typing `screen`. find the pid of your program: `ps aux| grep <myprogramname>` . Inside your screen session, type `reptyr <myprogrampid>` you should see your program running in your screen session now. You can kill your ssh session, screen will remain running waiting for you to reattach. To reattach, run `screen -ls` to find a list of available sessions and reattach using `screen -r <mysessionid>`

Comment: I've documented a safe way of doing it here, which answers the question:
https://rolfen.github.io/notes/entries/linux/process-detach.html

Answer (score 405, accepted):

Assuming that you have a program running in the foreground, **press ctrl-Z**, then:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 myprogram
$ disown -h %1
$ bg 1
[1]+ myprogram &
$ logout
```

If there is only one job, then you don't need to specify the job number. Just use `disown -h` and `bg`.

### Explanation of the above steps:

You press ctrl-Z. The system suspends the running program, displays a job number and a "Stopped" message and returns you to a bash prompt.

You type the `disown -h %1` command (here, I've used a `1`, but you'd use the job number that was displayed in the `Stopped` message) which marks the job so it ignores the `SIGHUP` signal (it will not be stopped by logging out).

Next, type the `bg` command using the same job number; this resumes the running of the program in the background and a message is displayed confirming that.

You can now log out and it will continue running..

Comment: Can you explain to me what exactly happens after each step?

Comment: You press ctrl-Z. The system suspends the running program, displays a job number and a "Stopped" message and returns you to a bash prompt. You type the "disown -h %1" command (here, I've used a "1", but you'd use the job number that was displayed in the "Stopped" message) which marks the job so it ignores the SIGHUP signal (it will not be stopped by logging out). Next, type the "bg" command using the same job number. This resumes the running of the program in the background and a message is displayed confirming that. You can now log out and it will continue running...

Comment: ...You should be aware that when you use the "bg" command the result is the same as if you'd run your program in the background with an ampersand (&). It won't have any output to stdout so it should be made to write output to a file (nohup will redirect standard output to nohup.out or ~/nohup.out if you don't redirect it yourself).

Comment: i test it, and doesn't work.. exit when i'm logout...

Comment: I tried disown on jobs already running in the background. It worked. But the jobs are no longer listed when running "jobs" command. So how do I find them now?

Comment: @ButtleButkus: You should be able to see them with `ps x`

Comment: Thanks for the hint @DennisWilliamson. I used `ps ax | grep tar` for example to see a `tar` command. Could also `grep` the `pid` if known.

Comment: in my case it only works in this order: 1. start program  2. CTR-Z  3. bg  4. disown  5. verify with `jobs'

Comment: This did not work for me. The programs never finished successfully after I logged out.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Found out that when you log out, the output stream dies, and therefore so does your process, even if you `disown`. You can redirect, e.g. `foo &>/dev/null &; disown %1`, but be aware of the redirection buffer getting larger over time. There's solutions to this problem [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe).

Comment: side-note: if you by any means need to switch the program to run in the "foreground" again, just use `fg`

Answer (score 103):

You should try using [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) and running it in the background:

```
nohup sleep 3600 &
```

Comment: Is there a way to bring this job back to foreground on logging in again?

Comment: Actually it redirects the output to `nohup.out` file in the same directory by default.

Comment: @LordLoh. Afaik, the only practical way to do this is to use `tmux` or `screen`.

Comment: this worked much better, thanks!
I just say `nohup <my program>` and then `CTRL-Z` + `bg`
Then I can logout. You can validate that it still runs by having another ssh looking at `top` and see the process keep going

Comment: You can also do `tail -f nohup.out` to see the output in real time, and then `kill` the PID if you need to restart.

Comment: you should use tmux: https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/, nohup didn't work for me with `julia myFile.jl` for whatever reason. Kept getting kill signals and freezes but tmux wored perfectly.

Answer (score 44):

I would try the program [screen](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/).

Comment: While screen is a mighty nice tool, nohup is probably better suited for this task. Screen is only needed when you require the program to be interactive, and to be able to go back to the application at a later time. To be entirely honest, I often find myself using screen for the exact same reason as the question above.

Comment: Even with non-interactive task, it's nice to see that the program finished without errors. It's also good practice to always use screen in case of disconnection.

Comment: alternative to screen would be `tmux`

Comment: This is the poster child for why link-only answers should never be used.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but it has been flagged as a link-only answer and in fact the link is dead. Would it be possible to expand it out to show a brief example of how to use screen, perhaps from the originally linked example (still available at https://web.archive.org/web/20090106170543/http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-tutorials/general-tutorials/using-screen/)?

Comment: And link can't even be updated since the post is now too short :/

Answer (score 19):

Start in the background:

```
./long_running_process options &
```

And disown the job before you log out:

```
disown
```

Comment: but the programme has already started to run..

Comment: And will it contine to run as root?

Comment: If the program is already running on the console and you can access the console it's running on hit "Ctrl+Z" to send it in the background and then disown the newly created job. 

As long as a process is started as root it will continue to run as root unless it drops privileges itself.

Comment: But the command is named 'disown',isn't that to say root will disown the program,and the program will not continue to run as root ?

Comment: After stopping the process with "Ctrl+Z" you send it in the background with "bg" before disowning it.

Comment: "disown" is just for abandoning control of a job it does not change the privileges of the process.

Answer (score 14):

You want [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).  See http://nixcraft.com/linux-software/313-ssh-nohup-connection.html

Comment: Link is not working anymore, but I guess this one is more or less the same: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/s/screen/), detach and reattach