# How to keep the task running after closing the ssh connection?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

How to keep the process running on remote server even if the ssh connection is closed?

Comment: Use: `nohup programname &`

Comment: @sat  I started dropbox on server in this way but it doesn't work. dropbox closed after I exit the terminal.

Comment: Asked and answered *ad nauseam*. Possible duplicate of [How to make a programme continue to run after log out from ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/954302/608639), [How to prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285015/608639), [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/q/8653), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use screen to detach a session. You connect to your ssh server, launch screen and then your computation...

At your next connection, `screen -a` to attach previous sessions

see : http://www.bangmoney.org/presentations/screen.html

Comment: thx for the info. i read it. should it be 'screen -r' to re-attach?

Answer (score 2):

Another idea would be to use [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) which works like screen but it is more flexible and easier to use (in my opinion). To keep a process running you could simply start a tmux session with the command `tmux`.

This will "open a new terminal" in which to run your programs, if you want you can give a name to the session to easily find it in case you have multiple sessions with the command `ctrl+b $` instead of using the default name (e.g. 0).

After running the programs you need in the `tmux` session, you simply detach from the session with `ctrl+b d` and go back to the normal terminal from which you can call `exit` and close your ssh connection.

When you log in again, you simply run `tmux attach -t <session_name>` to go inside the session where you left your tasks running.

`tmux` offers a lot of other functionalities too, like screen splitting inside the session with `ctrl+b %` or `ctrl+b "` for vertical and horizontal splitting. (you can move between different screens with `ctrl+b <arrow in the direction of the screen you want to go to>`.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/236158/tmux-vs-screen for a tmux vs screen comparison

Answer (score 1):

You can run your process/command inside a screen or tmux session,
Or you can do:

```
yourcmd &
disown
```

Answer (score 0):

All these Answers are correct but if you are initiating SSH from a code and giving bash commands then they don't work.  The best way is to use this command

`nohup command > /dev/null 2>&1 &`