# executing a script which runs even if i log off

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So, I have a long running script (of order few days) say `execute.sh` which I am planning to execute on a server on which I have a user account...

Now, I want to execute this script so that it runs forever even if I logoff or disconnect from the server?? 
How do i do that?
THanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a programme continue to run after log out from ssh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954302/how-to-make-a-programme-continue-to-run-after-log-out-from-ssh)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux: Prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client)

Answer (score 9):

You have a couple of choices. The most basic would be to use `nohup`:

```
nohup ./execute.sh
```

`nohup` executes the command as a child process and detaches from terminal and continues running if it receives `SIGHUP`. This signal means `sig hangup` and will getting triggered if you close a terminal and a process is still attached to it.

The output of the process will getting redirected to a file, per default `nohup.out` located in the current directory.

---

You may also use `bash`'s `disown` functionality. You can start a script in bash:

```
./execute.sh
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and then enter:

```
disown
```

The process will now run in background, detached from the terminal. If you care about the scripts output you may redirect output to a logfile:

```
./execute.sh > execute.log 2>&1
```

---

Another option would be to install `screen` on the remote machine, run the command in a screen session and detach from it. You'll find a lot of tutorials about this.

Answer (score 3):

`nohup` (no hangup) it and run it in the background:

```
nohup execute.sh &
```

Output that normally would have gone to the screen (STDOUT) will go to a file called nohup.out.