# Reading a stream with python. Need to have the script run continuously on server

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a python script that is continuously reading from an endless stream. i have tested it by running the script for days on my local machine. using:
`Python script.py`
and it keeps running since the stream is continuously sending data.

Now I have placed the file on a server and I want this to run continuously even when i log out of the server.
any help?

Comment: Might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617271/executing-a-script-which-runs-even-if-i-log-off

Comment: Run the service as a daemon, through systemd?