# Continue executing a program, after end of ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a script that runs an executable with 1000 different parameters (one per execution). This can take many hours. I run this in the lab computer. Now, I do this via ssh, from my home computer. Can I do an ssh, start executing the script, logout, but somehow allow the script to continue executing?

I mean the lab pc will still be open and I do not care about the stdout of the program. The interesting results will be written into a file, which I can check when I login again.

I tried to do so, but the script will stop executing as soon as I logout.

Comment: Pretty good explanation in [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](http://askubuntu.com/q/8653/143251).

Comment: Damn it, I checked for duplicates when I typed in the question. Maybe an improvement of this feature would be to check on other relevant sites too, like askubuntu. I am now reading the link @fedorqui

Comment: I completely agree on this. We have multiple duplicates over sites, that's why I always end up using google over SE search.

Comment: Do you think I should post on meta about this @fedorqui? I also answered my question, but it you think it's should be deleted, please let me know.

Comment: I strongly advise you to do so. In fact, some time ago [I commented this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic/13808#comment23874_13808) in meta askubuntu, but never went back to make it more visible. If you feel like, go ahead!

Comment: @fedorqui, I asked on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300598/search-for-duplicates-in-relevant-sites

Comment: This belongs on Unix & Linux (http://linux.stackexchange.com/), or Superuser.  I'll say more on your meta post.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see your point (and in meta) and I agree, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Asked and answered *ad nauseam*. Possible duplicate of [How to make a programme continue to run after log out from ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/954302/608639), [How to prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285015/608639), [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/q/8653), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when you tried, you put it in the background with `myscript &`, and then logged out.  Some GNU/Linux distros default to sending a `SIGHUP` to all processes that have the session tty as their tty (or some other way of finding processes from a login sessions, like a tree of parent PIDs, I forget.)

So, a solution is:

```
nohup myscript &
```

It's really that easy.  When run under `nohup`, you process will ignore the hang-up signal.  `nohup` redirects stdin from /dev/null if it was from the terminal, and stdout/stderr to `nohup.out`. Then you read `nohup.out`, which will be created in the directory from which you called your script.

tmux is really nice, and I use it all the time, but it's not actually needed for this.  (I actually use screen, but that's only because tmux didn't exist when I started using screen, and switching would incur some re-learning overhead.)

Answer (score 6):

Since I can't mark the question as a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session), since "The duplicate question must exist on Stack Overflow" and because I want to share my experience, I will answer my own question.

`tmux` and `screen` are the best answers in the duplicate. However, the first was not recognized in my Debian (probably need installing), while the later is ready to go and works fine, for this simple scenario:

- ssh into your remote box. Type `screen` Then start the process you want.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>. This will "detach" your screen session but leave your processes running. You can now log out of the remote box.
- If you want to come back later, log on again and type `screen -r` This will "resume" your screen session, and you can see the output of your process.

Also this comment seems good: "I will usually name my screen sessions using `screen -S name` to make it easier to connect to the correct one later. "

---

As deviantfan put it, " `tmux` needs installing. A simple `apt-get install tmux` as root is enough.".

Comment: Yes, tmux needs installing. A simple `apt-get install tmux` as root is enough.

Comment: Thank you @deviantfan, I updated my answer.

Comment: I never name my screen sessions.  I only ever have one per machine (per account).  So I just log in and `screen -dR`.  Although I recommend spending your time  learning/customizing tmux, since it's newer and better.