# Python connection refused from localhost when runningn on cron

Tags: python, flask, cron, python-requests

This is funny because most questions I found are the other way around.

1. I have a `flask` server that I start on debugging mode, listening on port 6000.
2. I have a script that accesses the url through localhost which sends back a JSON reply.

When I do an ssh tunnel using ssh -L and run the script that sends a request in my machine to localhost everything works fine. When I run the script directly from the server it also works fine. However, since I want to ultimately use a big data set, I setup a cron job. When the cron runs, the script crashes with connection refused error. I can see that the server is running after the script crashes and the port is correct on both.

I have no idea why this can happen. Any ideas are appreciated.

**Solution**

I couldn't figure out the reason or how to solve it, so I decided to run manually and put it in the background.

[How to make a programme continue to run after log out from ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954302/how-to-make-a-programme-continue-to-run-after-log-out-from-ssh)

Comment: /var/logs Message?

Comment: There's nothing relevant in the logs. The server's log doesn't show a request received and the script's log shows the connection refused exception.