# Keep process running on remote machine after exiting ssh session inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a bash script in which I login to a remote machine over ssh and run iperf and then logout and do other things locally. I want iperf to keep running after the bash script logs out. I have tried nohup, disown and setsid, but they don't seem to work when I use them inside the bash script. I have also tried running iperf inside another script, that didn't work either.

Here's the part of the script with nohup example:

```
ssh root@10.101.10.35 &>/dev/null & << EOF
nohup iperf -s -B 192.168.99.1 &>/dev/null &
EOF
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/311593/keeping-a-linux-process-running-after-i-logout

Comment: I don't think it is, because what is described in this is he logs in from a terminal and wants to keep it running after logging out. I am able to do this with nohup, disown etc. This is different because I'm running everything inside a bash script and it's not working this way.

Comment: Asked and answered *ad nauseam*. Possible duplicate of [How to make a programme continue to run after log out from ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/954302/608639), [How to prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285015/608639), [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/q/8653), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect `stdin,` `stdout` and `stderr` to somewhere else as opposed to your terminal like so:

```
ssh root@10.101.10.35 'iperf -s -B 192.168.99.1 < /dev/null > /tmp/iperf_combined.log 2>&1 &'
```

`stdin` is taken from `/dev/null` (nothing is entered)

`stdout` and `stderr` goes to `/tmp/iperf_combined.log`

The process will run on the remote machine until you will manually kill it or until the script/command will exit on its own.

Edit (as a reply to the poster's comment):

If you want to run multiple commands in the same `ssh` session, you may use:

```
ssh -T root@10.101.10.35 << EOF
iperf -s -B 192.168.99.1 < /dev/null > /tmp/iperf_combined_1.log 2>&1 &
iperf -s -B random_ip2 < /dev/null > /tmp/iperf_combined_2.log 2>&1 &
EOF
```

As per `ssh` man page:

```
-T      Disable pseudo-tty allocation.
```

Detailed explanation on `psqudo-tty` [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-a-pseudo-tty)

Comment: And if I wanted to run more commands than this one inside the same ssh session?

Comment: Please view my edited answer.