# Bash: How to leave a process running even after it's user logs out

Tags: bash

The only way i've heard of is using the cron, but id rather do it ad hoc. Is there another way in bash?

Comment: How about using `nohup`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954302/how-to-make-a-programme-continue-to-run-after-log-out-from-ssh

Answer (score 0):

Using nohup can also send both stdout and stderr to the same file of your interest other than nohup.out using the below method:

`nohup ./your-script.sh > my-output 2>&1 &`

You can keep the process running in background mode:

`./your-script.sh &`

OR

`(./yourscript.sh &) &`