# nohup process stops running a few minutes after terminal closed

Tags: php, ssh, server, nohup

I want a program (written in php) to run on a remote server even if after I logout. The program is very simple: it does nothing but sleep for 10s (just for a test), like the following:

```
function index() 
{
    while(true)
    {
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

So I connect to the remote server via SSH. And then launch the program like this:

```
  nohup php -f index.php &
```

I want it to run in the background on the server after I log out. But I find that everytime  after I close the terminal the program can only run for around 10 minutes and then stop, though it does not stop immediately after terminal closed. If I do not close the terminal, it can keep running forever (as expected). Could anyone tell me what is the reason? And how to solve the problem? I have also tried using "disown" as is suggested in this post but got the same problem: [How to make a programme continue to run after log out from ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954302/how-to-make-a-programme-continue-to-run-after-log-out-from-ssh)
By the way, I am using shared remote host, so it could be due to some server settings but it's strange because it works fine with terminal open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `disown` right after your `nohup` command.

If it still doesn't work, consider using `screen` instead. It is a useful utility allowing "virtual terminals" to run, even after logout.

1. Create a screen using `screen -dmS someName`. (e.g. `screen -dmS myPhpScript`)
2. Enter your screen using `screen -r`, your window will be cleared.
3. Execute your command (`php -f index.php`, no `&`!)
4. Exit the screen, by doing [Ctrl]+[A] (which seems to do nothing), and then pressing [D]. The screen will stay in background. You'll come back to the previous prompt (just before step 2), with a message indicating `[detached from XXXXX.someName]`.
5. You can get back to the screen using `screen -r` or `screen -x someName`.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not clear about step 2 and step 3. In Step2, shall I run the command in the background (i.e., with & appended at the end)? In Step 3, after I press "Ctrl + A" it does nothing, and then I press "D" still it does nothing. Did I do anything wrong? Please keep in mind that I connect to the server via SSH.

Comment: @TaoHu Whoops! I forgot a step. I edited my post. Also, don't use "&" again! [Here is a GIF](https://i.heysora.net/RfmM26.gif) in case you need one! (The "[detached from yourPhp]" comes after doing [Ctrl]+[A] and [D])

Comment: Hi HeySora, I tried your method and the process can work longer before it is killed. I finally have figured out that it is killed by the server. I am using A2hosting (shared hosting), which does not allow to run unattended process in the background. So even the screen process will be killed some time after logout. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a server issue. A2hosting does not allow a process to run in the background for their shared hosting. So the process will be killed some time (not immediately) after logout.