# Run Linux command in background and keep runing after closing SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, server, centos

I need to run a Perl script for several days processing something. On a linux Centos server, from the SSH terminal I run this command:

```
nohup perl script.cgi 2>&1 &
```

This runs the script in the background and writes the output to nohup.out.
The problem when I close the SSH terminal or even my internet connection disconnects the script terminates.

I need to keep this command running in the background on the server after I close
the SSH terminal.

Comment: Take a look at using screen. It may help.

Comment: Asked and answered *ad nauseam*. Possible duplicate of [How to make a programme continue to run after log out from ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/954302/608639), [How to prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285015/608639), [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/q/8653), etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **Terminal multiplexer** tools like screen, byobu or tmux.
I personally use screen. so install it on remote server via **sudo apt-get install screen**.

1. ssh into server
2. open screen session by **screen -S sessionname**
3. Now run your command (background/foreground both works)
4. now detach to your session by command **ctrl+a** then press **d**.
5. Now shut your pc and enjoy
6. now come back ssh into server then use command **screen -x sessionname** to reconnect the detached session.

Hurray! script is still running.

Answer (score 3):

you can either use screen or run the command using supervisor in linux systems.

- you can install screen using `sudo apt install screen`
- then use following command to run it.
- `screen -S test_command`
- `nohup perl script.cgi 2>&1 &`
- Then press ctrl+a and ctrl+d to leave that session running for whatever amount of time required until your server reboots.
- If you want to stop the command use `screen -x test_command`, then ctrl+c and use ctrl+a and ctrl+d to close screen or ctrl+a and ctrl+d to leave the screen session as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to run the command and exit the shell and keep the command running is using the ["at"](https://tecadmin.net/one-time-task-scheduling-using-at-commad-in-linux/) tool to schedule the job like this using the full script path:

```
echo "perl /home/username/www/script.cgi" | at now + 1 minute
```