# How to keep julia running after I close the command prompt or putty

Tags: linux, command-line, julia, putty

I am running a big julia simulation in AWS machine (linux). I use putty to run from the command line.

I type: `julia myscript.jl`

However, whenever I close the command prompt, or putty or my laptop, the run on the AWS server will stop. I wonder if anyone knows is there a way to keep julia running when I close the command line prompt. As I do not want to keep my laptop open and putty stay connected for several days

Thanks

Comment: `nohup julia myscript.jl &`

Comment: you can run that command in `screen`. For more details, refer [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/screen-command-in-linux-with-examples/)  URL

Comment: I want to throw tmux into the ring. Depending on your scenario a SystemD service would also be a good solution

Comment: This has been asked zillion times here already. For example: [How to make a programme continue to run after log out from ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954302/how-to-make-a-programme-continue-to-run-after-log-out-from-ssh) + Not to mention that such question are actually off-topic on [so].

Comment: @Ben - you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

[`dtach`](https://github.com/crigler/dtach) exists for this purpose. It will keep a process alive even if the terminal session that created the process is closed.

Once you log in through ssh, start a new dtach session:

```
$ dtach -A /tmp/my-dtach-session julia myscript.jl
```

Then detach from the session with `ctrl+\`.

Detaching will not kill your process. Here I check that it is still running after detaching:

```
[david@blue ~] $ ps aux | grep dtach                                       
david      506  0.0  0.0   8460  1484 ?        Ss   16:15   0:00 dtach -A /tmp/my-dtach-session ./pkg/julia-1.3.0/bin/julia
david      517  0.0  0.0   6140  2224 pts/2    S+   16:16   0:00 grep dtach
```

After you detach, you can close your ssh session like normal. If your process has not finished, you can log back in and reattach:

```
$ dtach -a /tmp/my-dtach-session
```