# Execute command with SSH.NET without blocking and keep it running after closing the connection

Tags: c#, .net, shell, ssh, ssh.net

I'm using the following code:

```
using (var client = new SshClient(host, user, pass))
{
    client.Connect();

    var terminal = client.RunCommand("/home/my-script.sh");
}
```

The `client.RunCommand` hangs because the command I'm using is creating a thread. I'd like the command to be executed and not wait for the thread to be finished. How would I dot it?

So to sum up, I want to:

- Send the command that creates a background work (thread)
- while the background work is being accomplished, I should be able to close the session/connection with the intention of the background work continuing

Reference: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Renci.SshNet/SshClient/RunCommand/php-sshclient-runcommand-method-examples.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really SSH.NET question, but rather a generic SSH/shell question.

See [How to make a program continue to run after log out from ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/954302/850848)

So this should do:

```
client.RunCommand("nohup /home/my-script.sh > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &");
```