# background process terminates after closing ssh client

Tags: linux, shell, process, ssh, background-process

My question is same as the ones I already found on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954302/how-to-make-a-programme-continue-to-run-after-log-out-from-ssh) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431521/run-a-command-in-a-shell-and-keep-running-the-command-when-you-close-the-session). But, for me `nohup` doesn't work. compiling `screen` gives errors and for disown, Control+Z does not make the process "stopped".

I run a data generation binary which writes data into a file and also prints status messages on the screen (stdout). I tried the following

```
nohup ./sp2b <options for sp2b> > output &
```

When I logout of the terminal and login back, the process is already killed. I actually would like to time it as well, so want to do

```
nohup time ./sp2b <options for sp2b> > output &
```

Why is nohup not working in my case?

Comment: why are you compiling screen? it should be readily available through your package manager

Comment: like apt-get? I don't have admin privileges. So I would actually prefer nohup like solution.

Comment: why you ampersanding in screen anyways ? load up screen ctrl a x - create a few sessions or one start your ob oopen a new session then do screen -d {detach } leave it to run ? - screen -r and its nuber to connect up again ctrl a 1 to go back to that screen and job without ampersand?

Comment: @vahid: he does not have screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Linux, how to prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285015/608639), [How to make a program continue to run after log out from ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/954302/608639), [Run a command in a shell and keep running the command when you close the session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/431521/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try something like this, instead of `screen` use `tmux` (a more modern alternative of screen), as you do not have root, we will install it locally.

```
mkdir tmp && cd tmp;
aptitude download tmux;
ar x tmux_*
tar xvf data.tar.gz
```

Now you can try `./usr/bin/tmux`, hopefully you will have dependencies installed, tmux has only a few. This worked on my machine.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this, but tmux depends on libevent and that is not installed on our server. Although I can compile and generate the binary of libevent and place it locally, I don't think there is an option to make tmux look in that folder for libevent(?). Why do you think the nohup option is not working for me?

Comment: yes, this is possible via changing the export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. you can set by `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/libevent/path:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: why the process is not responding to `NOHUP` and `suspend` signals, I do not know, i'm no expert. It's possible to explicitly ignore these signals though, the default behavior is to respect them. is this them program: http://dbis.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/index.php?project=SP2B ?

Comment: I tested it out with `/.sp2b_gen -t 5000000000000000` suspending works just fine for me, is this the right executable?

Comment: wow, thats a huge number, might takes days to finish. Yes, thats the executable that I am trying out with a lesser number as parameter. For suspending, did you do a control+z?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35315/discussion-between-uku-loskit-and-raghava)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `nohup` is that if you don't send the output to `> /dev/null 2>&1` 
then it will keep the output process opened (it will output to nohup.out). So if you close the terminal, you also close the output process.

Example:

```
nohup node somescrip.js >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```