# Detaching ipython notebook process without closing it?

Tags: python, linux, background, ipython, jupyter

I have an ipython noteboook where I am running a process that takes a very long time. I am using ipython `%R` magic in much of it, so I can't easily convert the notebook to a python script.

Is there a way I can open my notebook, run all, and then close my browser and disconnect from the terminal and still have the notebook running in the background that I can connect to later?

I see information on Stack Exchange about keeping the kernel alive, but I'm confused as to how this interfaces with the actual code running within a notebook.

Comment: This is the default behaviour... closing the notebook without explicitly stopping the kernel leaves the kernel running, go to `http://<host:port>/tree/notebooks#running` and you should see it is still running and will automatically attach if you open that notebook again.

Comment: @AChampion thanks for that; I found it at http://<host:port>/tree#running. When I open one of my running notebooks, it remains stuck at (Starting), at least for the past 10 minutes. I can see that my process is still running because htop still shows high CPU and memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **tmux**, to detach from running jupyter-notebook type `ctrl-C` then type tmux detach command : `ctrl-B, followed by d`

link for ***tmux*** setup : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42505000/7358899