# how to keep running my fastapi app even I close my aws terminal

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fastapi

I deploy my fast api on aws ec2 but the problem is I need to manually run `python3 -m uvicorn main:app` for start my fastapi app and if I close the terminal my fastapi app are not accessible from aws public ip.

here is ngnix config:

```
server {
    listen 80;   
    server_name aws ip;    
    location / {        
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;    
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to go down the ECS route, using`supervisord` or configuring `systemd` is a more resilient configuration than using screen or tmux - it'll handle restarts of the server and the application properly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tmux` or `screen` to start a long running process as described here: [keep server running on EC2 instance after ssh is terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193988/keep-server-running-on-ec2-instance-after-ssh-is-terminated).

These sessions will persist even after the terminal is closed.

If you need a more resilient solution (e.g. automatic restarts on failure, logging, etc.), I would look into using AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS). This will handle scaling, restarts, logging, and much more.