# Make gulp run on my server non-stop

Tags: javascript, server, gulp, gulp-watch

Is there any solution I can make gulp working on my server without me needing to connect with SSH and the writing `gulp js:watch sass:watch` ?
This is my current gulpconfig.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sassGlob = require('gulp-sass-glob');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('js:build', function() {
  gulp.src('js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('functions.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'))
});

gulp.task('js:watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['js:build'])
});

gulp.task('sass:build', function () {
    return gulp
        .src('css/global.scss')
        .pipe(sassGlob())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('css/**/*.scss', ['sass:build'])
});
```

Comment: Screen is exactly the tool you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431521/run-a-command-in-a-shell-and-keep-running-the-command-when-you-close-the-session

Comment: look into PM2 once you get sick of screen. i certainly never looked back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen program for linux is exactly what you are looking for:

- Install screen
- Open a new screen session: `screen -dR`
- Start gulp
- Disconnect from your screen session: `CTRL-A, d`

[Run a command in a shell and keep running the command when you close the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431521/run-a-command-in-a-shell-and-keep-running-the-command-when-you-close-the-session)

Answer (score 0):

you can run your script in background by appending `&`

```
//pointing to startMyWebsite.sh
./startMyWebsite &
```

Comment: does that keep running when the user disconnects?