# Google Compute Engine automatically kills python executable

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

I have a Python file that needs to be constantly running (a Telegram bot), but if I run in the background

```
python bot.py &
```

and then gracefully end the SSH connection, after a while the bot stops responding and I have to connect and launch it again.

How can I stop this from happening? If i cannot, how can I check when it is dead and relaunch it?

Comment: You sure the the instance you are using is not preemptible?

Comment: @RahulChawla yes

Comment: Where exactly you were running this executable files from? If you were running it from the [Google Cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/), this is one of its [usage limitation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits). Cloud Shell is intended for interactive use only. Non-interactive sessions will be ended automatically after a warning.

Comment: But, if you were running it inside from an instance and still want the command to be executed even after closing the shell, you have to use 'SCREEN', 'nohup' or 'disown'. You could check these discussion threads[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134924/i-am-using-why-isnt-the-process-running-in-the-background)-[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431521/run-a-command-in-a-shell-and-keep-running-the-command-when-you-close-the-session)-[3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and) about the usage of these commands. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chmod +x bot.py`

Do this to your python file to make it executable

`nohup /path/to/script/bot.py &`

The nohup will run the script in the background while the & will keep it running after you close the terminal

To check if your script is still running `ps -e | grep bot.py`

To see any errors run `cat nohup.out`

Comment: Why not just run the regular Python command instead of setting the execute permission?

Comment: Seems like a bunch of extra steps what you may not always have the option to do.

Comment: I don't understand how the main author doesn't have the option of running a few basic commands?

Comment: chmod is not always a basic command. The author of the script is not in full control of the server.