# How do I put an already-running process under nohup?

Tags: bash, shell, job-scheduling, nohup, interruption

I have a process that is already running for a long time and don't want to end it.

How do I put it under nohup (that is, how do I cause it to continue running even if I close the terminal?)

Comment: To anyone facing the same problem: Remember, that even if you type `yourExecutable &` and the outputs keep coming on the screen and `Ctrl+C` does not seem to stop anything, just blindly type `disown;` and press `Enter` even if the screen is scrolling with outputs and you can't see what you're typing. The process will get disowned and you'll be able to close the terminal without the process dying.

Answer (score 1570, accepted):

Using the [Job Control](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html) of bash to send the process into the background:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to stop (pause) the program and get back to the shell.
2. `bg` to run it in the background.
3. `disown -h [job-spec]` where [job-spec] is the job number (like `%1` for the first running job; find about your number with the `jobs` command) so that the job isn't killed when the terminal closes.

Comment: As the question was how to "put it under nohup",`disown -h` perhaps is the more exact answer: "make disown behave more like nohup (i.e. the jobs will stay in your current shell's process tree until you exit your shell) This allows you to see all the jobs that this shell started." (from [http://www.quantprinciple.com/invest/index.php/docs/tipsandtricks/unix/jobcontrol/])

Comment: How do I recover the job later? I can see it running using ps -e.

Comment: You can't see the output of a job after a `disown`, disown makes a process a daemon, which means standard input/output are redirected to /dev/null. So, if you plan to disown a job, its better to start it with logging into a file, e.g. `my_job_command | tee my_job.log`

Comment: is it possible somehow to do something like 'my_job_command | tee my_job.log' _after_ the command is already running?

Comment: `disown` disassociates any pipes from the process.  To reattach pipes, use `gdb` as described in [this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31830/11884).  More specifically, [this post](http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/).

Comment: Why is a "jobspec" a job number prefixed with a `%`? I can't find this anywhere in documentation, can anyone give me a pointer?

Comment: @CoryKendall [Here's some info on it](http://structure.usc.edu/bash/bashref_7.html).

Comment: The `bg` command shows the job number already on screen (the number between square brackets, like `[1]`).

Comment: @Node according to this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and disowned processes will fail if the terminal closes and the program tries to read from standard input or write from standard output.

Comment: how do you "reown" a process after disowning it?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade `fg` resumes a process when you send it to background. E.g., `while :; do sleep 5; echo "hooray"; done` `Enter` `bg %1` `Enter` `fg %1`. This doesn't work for disown, which "[removes] jobs from current shell"

Comment: Weird: After `disown -h %1`, I still see the process's output in the shell. The process does seem to be properly nohup'd; I can close the shell and it keeps running. This is on Ubuntu 16 LTS.

Comment: @StefanReich  According to this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and , disown only prevents the SIGHUP signal from being sent to the process when the shell is terminated. However, it doesn't prevent the proccess from attempting to use stdin/stdout to read from/write to the shell.

In this case, the correct answer would be the one presented by Dale.

Comment: -h switch is unavailable in RHEL. However, even w/out using it, the process appears to be running ok as an orphan.

Comment: Should it be (1 AND 2)  OR 3? That's not really clear from the answer

Comment: Where does the standard output go after `disown`? Does it go to `nohup.out`?

Answer (score 216):

Suppose for some reason <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is also not working, go to another terminal, find the process id (using `ps`) and run:

```
kill -SIGSTOP PID 
kill -SIGCONT PID
```

`SIGSTOP` will suspend the process and `SIGCONT` will resume the process, in background. So now, closing both your terminals won't stop your process.

Comment: Yes, thats a OS problem, kill does not work with Cygwin on Windows.

Comment: Also very useful if the job is started from another ssh session.

Comment: Just remember to do the `disown %1` in the first terminal before closing it.

Comment: This is useful since I started a graphical interface with a console (in my case I started from konsole `kwin` after a crash without thinking of the consequences). So if I stopped kwin, everything would have frozen and I had no possibilities to run `bg`!

Comment: @fred I didn't do this and it seemed to continue running. Possible or did I hit the wrong PID?

Comment: You shouldn't use hardcoded signal numbers; use names.

Comment: @jchevali you can request an edit if you feel that would add to the answer.

Comment: More easy to remember is just `kill -SIGTSTP PID` and `kill -SIGCONT PID`.

Comment: This is very useful, since sometimes, especially with `nohup <command> &` CTRL+Z doesn't work. So, I vote for this as the right answer. No need to disown, all terminals could be closed safely.

Comment: This did not work for me in zsh. It paused the process (same as ctrl+Z) but then -SIGCONT in the new tty only causes it to be resumed in the foreground of the original tty. This is using zsh 5.8

Answer (score 102):

The command to separate a running job from the shell ( = makes it nohup) is `disown` and a basic shell-command.

From bash-manpage (man bash):

> disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ...]
>
> Without options, each jobspec is removed from the table of active jobs. If the -h option is given, each jobspec is not
>   removed from the table, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the shell receives a SIGHUP. If no jobspec is
>   present, and neither the -a nor the -r option is supplied, the current job is used. If no jobspec is supplied, the -a option
>   means to remove or mark all jobs; the -r option without a jobspec argument restricts operation to running jobs. The return
>   value is 0 unless a jobspec does not specify a valid job.

That means, that a simple

```
disown -a
```

will remove all jobs from the job-table and makes them nohup

Comment: `disown -a` removes all jobs. A simple `disown` only removes the current job. As the man page in the answer says.

Answer (score 85):

These are good answers above, I just wanted to add a clarification:

You can't `disown` a pid or process, you `disown` a job, and that is an important distinction.

A job is something that is a notion of a process that is attached to a shell, therefore you have to throw the job into the background (not suspend it) and then disown it.

Issue:

```
%  jobs
[1]  running java 
[2]  suspended vi
%  disown %1
```

See http://www.quantprinciple.com/invest/index.php/docs/tipsandtricks/unix/jobcontrol/
for a more detailed discussion of Unix Job Control.

Answer (score 59):

Unfortunately `disown` is specific to bash and not available in all shells.

Certain flavours of Unix (e.g. AIX and Solaris) have an option on the `nohup` command itself which can be applied to a running process:

```
nohup -p pid
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Comment: Only for `AIX` and `Solaris`. "The AIX and Solaris versions of nohup have a -p option that modifies a running process to ignore future SIGHUP signals. Unlike the above-described disown builtin of bash, nohup -p accepts process IDs.". [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

Answer (score 30):

Node's answer is really great, but it left open the question how can get stdout and stderr redirected. I found a solution on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process/31830#31830), but it is also not complete. I would like to merge these two solutions. Here it is:

For my test I made a small bash script called loop.sh, which prints the pid of itself with a minute sleep in an infinite loop.

```
$./loop.sh
```

Now get the PID of this process somehow. Usually `ps -C loop.sh` is good enough, but it is printed in my case.

Now we can switch to another terminal (or press ^Z and in the same terminal). Now `gdb` should be attached to this process.

```
$ gdb -p <PID>
```

This stops the script (if running). Its state can be checked by `ps -f <PID>`, where the `STAT` field is 'T+' (or in case of ^Z 'T'), which means (man ps(1))

```
    T Stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced
    + is in the foreground process group

(gdb) call close(1)
$1 = 0
```

Close(1) returns zero on success.

```
(gdb) call open("loop.out", 01102, 0600)
$6 = 1
```

Open(1) returns the new file descriptor if successful.

This open is equal with `open(path, O_TRUNC|O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR)`. 
Instead of `O_RDWR` `O_WRONLY` could be applied, but `/usr/sbin/lsof` says 'u' for all std* file handlers (`FD` column), which is `O_RDWR`.

I checked the values in /usr/include/bits/fcntl.h header file.

The output file could be opened with `O_APPEND`, as `nohup` would do, but this is not suggested by `man open(2)`, because of possible NFS problems.

If we get -1 as a return value, then `call perror("")` prints the error message. If we need the errno, use `p errno` gdb comand.

Now we can check the newly redirected file. `/usr/sbin/lsof -p <PID>` prints:

```
loop.sh <PID> truey    1u   REG   0,26        0 15008411 /home/truey/loop.out
```

If we want, we can redirect stderr to another file, if we want to using `call close(2)` and `call open(...)` again using a different file name.

Now the attached `bash` has to be released and we can quit `gdb`:

```
(gdb) detach
Detaching from program: /bin/bash, process <PID>
(gdb) q
```

If the script was stopped by `gdb` from an other terminal it continues to run. We can switch back to loop.sh's terminal. Now it does not write anything to the screen, but running and writing into the file. We have to put it into the background. So press `^Z`.

```
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./loop.sh
```

(Now we are in the same state as if `^Z` was pressed at the beginning.)

Now we can check the state of the job:

```
$ ps -f 24522
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
<UID>    <PID><PPID>  0 11:16 pts/36   S      0:00 /bin/bash ./loop.sh
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 ./loop.sh
```

So process should be running in the background and detached from the terminal. The number in the `jobs` command's output in square brackets identifies the job inside `bash`. We can use in the following built in `bash` commands applying a '%' sign before the job number :

```
$ bg %1
[1]+ ./loop.sh &
$ disown -h %1
$ ps -f <PID>
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
<UID>    <PID><PPID>  0 11:16 pts/36   S      0:00 /bin/bash ./loop.sh
```

And now we can quit from the calling bash. The process continues running in the background. If we quit its PPID become 1 (init(1) process) and the control terminal become unknown.

```
$ ps -f <PID>
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
<UID>    <PID>     1  0 11:16 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash ./loop.sh
$ /usr/bin/lsof -p <PID>
...
loop.sh <PID> truey    0u   CHR 136,36                38 /dev/pts/36 (deleted)
loop.sh <PID> truey    1u   REG   0,26     1127 15008411 /home/truey/loop.out
loop.sh <PID> truey    2u   CHR 136,36                38 /dev/pts/36 (deleted)
```

**COMMENT**

The gdb stuff can be automatized creating a file (e.g. loop.gdb) containing the commands and run `gdb -q -x loop.gdb -p <PID>`. My loop.gdb looks like this:

```
call close(1)
call open("loop.out", 01102, 0600)
# call close(2)
# call open("loop.err", 01102, 0600)
detach
quit
```

Or one can use the following one liner instead:

```
gdb -q -ex 'call close(1)' -ex 'call open("loop.out", 01102, 0600)' -ex detach -ex quit -p <PID>
```

I hope this is a fairly complete description of the solution.

Comment: Very informative indeed, and likely to work well in simple cases. But be warned, more complex cases may fail miserably. I had one of those today: My process had spawened another process that did the output (presumably to stderr), but had stdout hooked up for communication with its master. Redirecting the masters FDs was effectless because the child had inherited stderr, and closing the childs stdout failed the master that was waiting on the other end of the pipe. X-| Bettern know your processes well before you try this.

Comment: @cmaster You can check if a handle is redirected using `lsof` (the file handle's name is `pipe`, not like `/dev/pts/1`) or by `ls -l /proc/<PID>/fd/<fd>` (this shows the symlink of the handle). Also subprocesses still can have not redirected outputs, which should be redirected to a file.

Comment: The best answer on how to bring a detached process back to a terminal! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 21):

Simple and easiest steps

1. `Ctrl + Z` ----------> *Suspends the process*
2. `bg`       --------------> *Resumes and runs background*
3. `disown %1` -------------> *required only if you need to detach from the terminal*

Comment: Carefull.  This way process is still bound to terminal and will terminate if terminal is closed.

Comment: `disown -h %1` seems to avoid SIGHUP (completely detach process from terminal).

Answer (score 6):

To send running process to nohup (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

`nohup -p pid` , it did not worked for me

Then I tried the following commands and it worked very fine

1. Run some SOMECOMMAND, 
   say `/usr/bin/python /vol/scripts/python_scripts/retention_all_properties.py 1`.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to stop (pause) the program and get back to the shell.
3. `bg` to run it in the background.
4. `disown -h` so that the process isn't killed when the terminal closes.
5. Type `exit` to get out of the shell because now you're good to go as the operation will run in the background in its own process, so it's not tied to a shell.

This process is the equivalent of running `nohup SOMECOMMAND`.

Answer (score 5):

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>  - this will pause the job (not going to cancel!)
2. `bg` - this will put the job in background and return in running process
3. `disown -a` - this will cut all the attachment with job (so you can close the terminal and it will still run)

These simple steps will allow you to close the terminal while keeping process running.

It wont put on `nohup` (based on my understanding of your question, you don't need it here).

Comment: I think the behaviour for disown -a is to cut attachment with all jobs.
However, it doesn't shutdown the stdin/stdout pipelines, which means that the process will still try to write (/read) from the terminal

Answer (score 3):

On my AIX system, I tried

```
nohup -p  processid>
```

This worked well. It continued to run my process even after closing terminal windows. We have ksh as default shell so the `bg` and `disown` commands didn't work.