# Keep a process alive without nohup

Tags: process, nohup

I started a script on the server and did not use nohup, but I have to disconnect. Is there any way I can keep it running? Its a long 27 hr process.

Comment: Probably dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625409/how-do-i-put-an-already-running-process-under-nohup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> to suspend the job, then `bg` to resume it in the background.

Comment: Under bash, you'd also need to disown the job - see `help disown`

Answer (score 1):

You could also run it in a 'screen'.

I use this all the time when administering systems remotely, because if I'm on the road I often have a really poor internet connection.

man screen for more information