# Scala start Play server in production

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2.0 app deployed on EC2 and I start the app with `play start` and it runs in the background, I can hit `Ctrl-D` and the process will continue to run in the background but then it dies after a while (15 or 20 mins?), not sure why. I usually exit the ssh session after starting the app, I'm hoping that's not the reason.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably closing as a result of the hang-up signal from you ending your `ssh` session.  Try launching the Unix program `screen` (a multiplexer), then launching your Play server like normal.  Then, before logging out of `ssh`, press `ctrl + a` and then `d` to "detach" the `screen` session.  This will leave Play running in the background (through `screen`), even after your `ssh` session ends.

Comment: Have you tried disowning the process? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/625436/51280

Comment: @Destin, yeah it was due to my `ssh` session ending and `nohup` works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`nohup play start` works for me.

Comment: nohup activator run doesn't work anymore. Had to do it this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25852899/2426994 way.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the following startup script (on CentOS) for my Play app, seems to work fine, it puts it in the background and in its own process group and session so it's immune to hangups etc. The tip about `play stage` and `target/start` comes from [Guillaume Bort](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/BlV4c3q8hxE) and is "the proper way of doing it".

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# chkconfig: 2345 98 1
# description: MyApp application
#

case "$1" in
start)
  su - apps <<'EOF'
cd /opt/myapp || exit 1
PATH=/opt/play-2.1.1:$PATH
echo "Starting MyApp..."
play stage 
setsid target/start < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 & 
EOF
  ;;
stop)
  su - apps <<'EOF'
cd /opt/myapp || exit 1
PATH=/opt/play-2.1.1:$PATH
echo "Stopping MyApp..."
play stop
EOF
  ;;
esac
```

You can verify it's isolated with:

```
ps -e -o user,pid,ppid,pgrp,sid,command | grep -i play
```

You'll see something like:

```
apps      2949     1  2949  2949 java -cp target/staged/* play.core.server.NettyServer target/..
```

Meaning `init` (pid `1`) is its parent and it's isolated in its own process group (`2949`).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you prepare the project deployment binary by using the stage command that the activator (formerly play) script takes. You can run that binary in the background, it can be found in the path which the second command in the code below shows.

```
./activator stage
target/universal/stage/bin/project-name &
```

Comment: You should probably disown the process afterwards as well.

Answer (score 0):

For play 2.2.3 ... play "start -Dhttp.port=8080" worked for me!