# play 2.2.1 application deployment in the background and exit logs without using control+D

Tags: playframework-2.2

I am writing a script to deploy a play 2.2.1 application.However I have noticed after running the application using command play "start 8084", the application is running at 8084 port but I have to do cntrl+D to exit logs and go back to command promt in ubuntu. 
Is there a way to go back to console without using cntrl+d....because I have to do this using shell script.

Also I  have used stage. but I am getting the following error:

```
[error] Not a valid command: play (similar: apply, last, alias)
[error] Not a valid project ID: play
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: play (similar: clean)
[error] play
```

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use something like this with `playframework 2.2`:

1. Run `play dist` for a project
2. Unzip the prepared `zip` archive somewhere (it is located in the `target\universal` folder of your application). The start script will be located at `bin/<app_name>`
3. Run the project like this: `bash /path/to/your/app/bin/<app_name> -Dhttp.port=8084 &` (note the ampersand in the end)

If you are planning to use `ssh` consider disowning the process or running it with `nohup` (you may read the details here: [Scala start Play server in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729443/scala-start-play-server-in-production)) so that the application does not shutdown when you close the ssh session:

`bash /path/to/your/app/bin/<app_name> -Dhttp.port=8084 & disown`