# How to make a program reading stdin run in background on linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a program reading from standard input in a `while` loop. I need to run it in the background, even after I close the console. If the name of the program is `prog`, how can I do that?

Comment: If I type the command  echo -e "\004" |./prog  &,after I close the console,the process end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i put the current running linux process in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676457/how-can-i-put-the-current-running-linux-process-in-background)

Comment: If you close the console, how can it read from stdin?

Comment: What is your `stdin`? A tty? And **why** do you ask? Please edit your question to motivate it

Comment: For backgrounding a process and having it run detached from the console/terminal it started on: `$ bg %1; disown %1`. (Or whatever PID your program has.)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to provide stdin redirected from some source other than the keyboard (which disappears when you log out), but

```
nohup prog < inputfile > outputfile 2> errorlogfile
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

When I started with UNIX 24 years ago I had the same question.

If you are a newbie then what you are looking for is `tmux`: Here you can start a program that reads from STDIN, log out, log back in some time later, and continue.

Otherwise `nohup` is the correct answer.

Comment: `tmux` is a new one on me, but it looks bloody useful. Guess I have some more reading to do.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `screen`

```
$ screen
$ prog < inputfile
# CTRL-A, CTRL-D to detach from the screen tty
# Log out or close console; log back in, or start another console later. 
# To re-attach to the screen tty:
$ screen -r
```