# How to save a program's running history?

Tags: bash

I'm running a program called `gatk-picard.sh` and it's printing out the running history/log (`INFO*` rows below). Since the program will take about 20 hours to finisn and I wanted to put it on running when I am leaving my office but would check the running history in my home. How to save these history lines automatically after it's done?

What I have tried was $gatk-picard.sh > log but seems not working.

```
$ ./gatk-picard.sh 
INFO  16:08:50,858 HelpFormatter - -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
INFO  16:08:50,861 HelpFormatter - The Genome Analysis Toolkit (GATK) v3.6-0-g89b7209, Compiled 2016/06/01 22:27:29 
INFO  16:08:50,861 HelpFormatter - Copyright (c) 2010-2016 The Broad Institute 
INFO  16:08:50,862 HelpFormatter - For support and documentation go to https://www.broadinstitute.org/gatk 
INFO  16:08:50,862 HelpFormatter - [Fri Sep 16 16:08:50 EDT 2016] Executing on Linux 3.13.0-95-generic amd64 
INFO  16:08:50,862 HelpFormatter - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_102-b14 JdkDeflater 
linux
```

Comment: have you tried `gatk-picard.sh 2&>1 > log`

Comment: no, what does `2&>1` means?

Comment: redirect error output to standard output.

Comment: Use nohup as well - perhaps read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676457/how-can-i-put-the-current-running-linux-process-in-background/13676865#13676865

Comment: You could also run the program under `screen` or `tmux`. This will allow you to detach the terminal and reconnect to it later.

Comment: To expand on Barmar's comment, `tmux` will not only allow you to 'connect later', but you can go home and connect to the tty remotely.  (`screen` will also let you do that, but if you are not yet familiar with these tools I strongly recommend learning `tmux` rather than `screen`.  The functionality is similar, but (IMO) `tmux` is superior.)

Answer (score 0):

### Use *nohup* Utility

If you don't need to interact with the script, you can run it under *nohup*:

```
nohup gatk-picard.sh &
```

You can then read or monitor the logfile, even while the program continues to run. For example:

```
tail -F nohup.out
```