# How to run all Makefiles in parallel?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to run all Makefiles under sub-directory.

But problem is that I can't run all Makefiles in parallel.

How do I run the Makefiles at once in parallel?

I came across the snippet code as the below

```
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

all: $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@

.PHONY: all $(SUBDIRS)
```

or

```
all:
    cd library  && $(MAKE) all && cd ..
    cd programs && $(MAKE) all && cd ..
    cd tests    && $(MAKE) all && cd ..
```

But they can't all run in parallel.

Comment: If this is unix, have you tried adding a single ampersand '&' to the make line?

Comment: @redwards Would you please let me know how to add '&' ?

Comment: With your first example, "$(MAKE) -C $@ &".  In unix, this runs command as a shell job.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I put the current running linux process in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676457/how-can-i-put-the-current-running-linux-process-in-background)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The recommended way to parallelize make runs is to use the -j option.

```
$ make -j
or 
$ make -j <jobs/threads>
```

The -j option takes an optional parameter of number of jobs/threads to use, which usually should track to the number of logical cpus (nproc). The default is unlimited.