# Exit zsh, but leave running jobs open?

Tags: bash, zsh, jobs

Just switched from bash to zsh.

In bash, background tasks continue running when the shell exits. For example here, `dolphin` continues running after the `exit`:

```
$ dolphin .
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 dolphin .
$ bg
[1]+ dolphin . &
$ exit
```

This is what I want as the default behavior.

In contrast, zsh's behavior is to warn about running jobs on `exit`, then close them if you `exit` again. For example here, `dolphin` is closed when the second `exit`-command actually exits the shell:

```
 % dolphin .
^Z
zsh: suspended  dolphin .
 % bg
[1]  + continued  dolphin .
 % exit
zsh: you have running jobs.
 % exit
```

How do I make zsh's default behavior here like bash's?

Answer (score 252):

Start the program with `&!`:

```
dolphin &!
```

The `&!` ([or equivalently, `&|`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243315/in-zsh-whats-the-difference-between-and/243316#243316)) is a zsh-specific shortcut to both *background* **and** *disown* the process, such that exiting the shell will leave it running.

Comment: For completeness, can you also list how to disown it once it is already started?

Comment: @trusktr [There's a different question about disowning the foreground process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/625409/777586).  I think it's best kept separate for clarity.  For anyone interested in zsh specifically, I've asked [a question on U&L SE about how to create a faster workflow for disowning the foreground process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/223432/16404).

Comment: I like this solution and I'll implement it for individual commands, but I'm still looking for a way to change Zsh's default behavior.

Comment: @Vince Do you mean changing the default to always disown backgrounded processes? If so, you can do that with `setopt nohup` in your `~/.zshrc`. Then starting a command backgrounded with `&` will also always disown it. Though by default zsh will still remind you that you have running jobs when you attempt to exit. You can turn that off too with `setopt nocheckjobs`.

Comment: @Anko I think `setopt nocheckjobs` does what I want. Now I've found the available options in `man zshoptions`. I'd like to turn off the warning. I know when I have background processes and I don't need it. I'd like it to close background processes unless I started them with `nohup`. I currently use this with a shell function that runs [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) in the background with `nohup`. When I type `pycharm .` it runs `nohup charm $@ &`. It doesn't close when I close the terminal, but I still get that warning and have to type `exit` twice.

Comment: Why doesn't this work when inside an alias?

Comment: @DimiDak Works fine for me. `alias z="chromium &|"`

Comment: @Anko I forgot to mention my alias contains also sudo. So maybe that's the reason.

Comment: @DimiDak Also works fine for me. `alias z="sudo sleep 1 &|"`. Construct minimal examples like this, and you'll narrow it down eventually.

Comment: @Anko , well it doesn't work for some reason. If I use sudo for some other command first, then it works. Also why pipe and not exclamation mark as the answer suggests?

Answer (score 67):

From the [zsh documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html):

> **`HUP`**
>
> ... In zsh, if you have a background job running when the shell exits, the shell will assume you want that to be killed; in this case it is sent a particular signal called `SIGHUP`... If you often start jobs that should go on even when the shell has exited, then you can set the option `NO_HUP`, and background jobs will be left alone.

So just set the `NO_HUP` option:

```
% setopt NO_HUP
```

Comment: If you don't want the warning, yes.

Comment: Despite what the documentation says, this still kills the job for whatever reason. Tested on zsh 5.8: start an infinite loop-sleep script as a process, press ctrl+Z, run setopt, exit, and the process is killed.

Answer (score 47):

I have found that using a combination of `nohup`, `&`, and `disown` works for me, as I don't want to permanently cause jobs to run when the shell has exited.

```
nohup <command> & disown
```

While just `&` has worked for me in `bash`, I found when using only `nohup`, `&`, or `disown` on running commands, like a script that calls a java run command, the process would still stop when the shell is exited.

- `nohup` makes the command ignore `NOHUP` and `SIGHUP` signals from the shell
- `&` makes the process run in the background in a subterminal
- `disown` followed by an argument (the index of the job number in your jobs list) prevents the shell from sending a `SIGHUP` signal to child processes. Using `disown` without an argument causes it to default to the most recent job.

I found the `nohup` and `disown` information at [this page](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-detach-linux-process-from-shell.html), and the `&` information in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338895/943773).

**Update**

When I originally wrote this, I was using it for data processing scripts/programs. For those kinds of use cases, something like [`ts`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/tsp.1.html) (task-spooler), works nicely.

Answer (score 8):

I typically use `screen` for keeping background jobs running.

**1) Create a screen session:**

```
screen -S myScreenName
```

**2) Launch your scripts,services,daemons or whatever**

**3) Exit (detach) screen-session with**

```
screen -d
```

or
shortcut `ALT+A then d`

---

After few hundreds of years - if you want to resume your session (reattach):

```
screen -r myScreenName
```

If you want to know if there's a screen-session, its name and its status (attached or detached):

```
screen -ls
```

---

This solution works on all terminal interpreters like bash, zsh etc.
See also `man screen`

Comment: A note for MacOS users, the keyboard shortcut to detach from screen was Control+A, then D. Also this was my only option when I left a process running and yielding to stdout, writing screen -d there wouldn't help.

Comment: Nice but nothing to do with the Q which is specifically about how to keep bg tasks running when exiting ZSH.

Comment: @RichieHH I don't believe you are correct. You can spawn "background tasks" and allow them to run when exiting ZSH: `screen -d -m your command` will spawn a screen session for `your command`, and a following `exit` will exit the shell.