# When opening Unity 3D from command line, quitting the terminal quits Unity

Tags: bash, unity-game-engine, terminal, zsh

I am opening a Unity 3D project and all its associated stuff with the following zsh function:

```
function room() {
    smerge ~/apps/x/
    code /Users/x/apps/x/Assets
    /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.2.7f1/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -projectPath /Users/x/apps/x
}
```

But when I do this, the terminal never stops running the Unity executable, and doesn't let me run any more commands. Look:

[image]

It's stuck! Worse, when I quit the terminal or break the process, Unity also quits, as it's attached. I just want Unity to open, and then return control to the terminal -- I'm only opening unity by the command line as a quick way to open a project -- not to do any builds or tests. Is there something I'm missing? Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302913/exit-zsh-but-leave-running-jobs-open

Comment: @RetiredNinja This worked wonderfully. Thank you! Answer, so I can make it the answer?

Comment: Yup! It did. Thanks! I've posted an answer. If you post yours, I"ll accept it...