# Sending command to program in Debian

Tags: debian, putty

I'm running a program on a Debian machine. It run it in the background by using the following command: "nohup ./samp03svr &". As I'm told the "&" symbol is what makes it run in the background.

My problem is that I need to send commands to the program later. Can I get it back from background somehow?

I'm using PuTTy tu access my machine, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this with the `fg` command. I'm going to show this with a silly `ls` command which finishes long before you get the chance to give commands (I assume you use something like stdin to get them to your program)

eg:

```
ls &
[1] 10970 #you'll see output similar to this.

fg %1 #get  job one back to the foreground hence the name fg.
```

notice the [1] 10970 the[1] is the jobnumber you can also use the command `jobs` to show which jobs are currently in the background. Ofcourse you should replace ls with `nohup ./samp03svr &`

hope this helps cheers,

Comment: Something happened, but i'm not sure what.. And not what I meant sadly. What should I do insted of "ls", as I know it displays files in my current dir. I'll try to explain what I need, because I believe you misunderstood me(or I did): There's a program running(on Windows it's like a console) and I want to send a command "say text" to it, which should act accordingly in the game

Comment: please see my edit. Also your question is a bit vague, since you don't specify what you mean by a command. How your program should get those commands etc.

Comment: Ah, but that will run it again, wont it ? It might be hard to understand, because I do not know correct terms... By "Send commands" I want to do something simmiliar to writing text into console on Windows

Comment: Nope the program state is in the background. fg just gets the program back to the foreground so you are able to provide input via the standard input for example.

Comment: Well I now can to write text, I'll asume that it's sent to the program and it just runs differently on linux and I can't use it that way... One more question, how do I send it back to background?

Comment: by using the keycombination `ctrl+z`. But specify what you mean "it's send to the program". You should tell by what way it should be send to the program, since it doesn't occur by magic.

Comment: That stopped the program

Comment: No that does't stop the program is puts the program in the background see eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625409/how-do-i-put-an-already-running-process-under-nohup

Comment: About that sending, the console knows how to send it to the program. I need to send it to the console. About stopping. Recap, I run it with nohup. When I want i use fg to get it from the background. And then if I press **ctrl+z** it outputs: [2]+ stopped  nohup ./samp03svr

Comment: and then run bg %2 and then the program will run in the back ground.

Comment: Finally. I didn't quite achieve what I wanted but atleast I learned something. I thankyou for your patience and help