# glassfish stops when i close putty window

Tags: linux, shell, glassfish, job-control

I have Glassfish up and running on a Solaris machine.

I am using putty to connect to that machine.

I start the domain using

```
asadmin start-domain
```

I also have remote administration enabled. I am able to login to the admin portal at this time.

The instant i close the putty window the glassfish instance is not longer running.

On a windows machine you can start the domain as a service. What is the equvalent for linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish has a command to create a service.

```
sudo glassfish4/bin/asadmin create-service
```

Then start the domain like so (the above command prints this path for you)

```
* /usr/bin/svcs  -a | grep domain1  // status
* /usr/sbin/svcadm enable domain1 // start
* /usr/sbin/svcadm disable domain1 // stop
* /usr/sbin/svccfg delete domain1 // uninstall
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use [init scripts](https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/how_to_run_glassfish_v3) or system daemons (this is the equivalent to a service) you must make sure all started programs are detached from the console.

You typically use "nohup asadmin start-domain" for this. You can also do it with `disown -h` after the fact, as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625409/how-do-i-put-an-already-running-process-under-nohup)