# Django HttpResponse Internal Server Error when logged out

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a JQuery request for JSON data in my Django app (which started in vitrualenv with `uwsgi` and `nginx`):

```js
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
    var obl  = "/raj/?raj=" + data.id;
    $.getJSON( obl, function( raj_data ) {
        ...
        } );
    } );
```

and corresponding view:

```py
def rcoato(request):
    response_data = SprRegion.objects.values('id').get(Q(id=request.GET['region']))
    response_data = json.dumps(response_data)
    return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type='application/javascript')
```

It works fine, JSON data returned, but **only when I logged in via SSH**.
I and start my application with:

```bash
source virtualenv/bin/activate
uwsgi --xml /home/rino/sites/centre/uwsgi.xml &
```

When I logged out (with `setopt no_hup` and `setopt no_checkjobs`), my app works partially - HTML pages are rendering, static files are handling, but requests to `/raj/?raj=...` raises Internal Server Error 500.

My `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
       listen 8081;
       server_name localhost;
       access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx_centre_access.log;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx_centre_error.log;

       location /static {    
           autoindex on;    
           alias /home/rino/sites/centre/centre/static/;    
       }

       location / {
           uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
           include /home/rino/sites/centre/uwsgi_params;
       }
}
```

`uwsgi` config:

```xml
<uwsgi>
  <socket>127.0.0.1:3031</socket>
  <processes>5</processes>
  <pythonpath>/home/rino/sites/centre</pythonpath>
  <chdir>/home/rino/sites/centre/centre</chdir>
  <wsgi-file>/home/rino/sites/centre/centre/wsgi.py</wsgi-file>
  <pidfile>/tmp/centre-master.pid</pidfile>
  <plugin>python3</plugin>
  <max-requests>5000</max-requests>
  <harakiri>40</harakiri>
  <master>true</master>
  <threads>2</threads>
</uwsgi>
```

`cat nginx_centre_error.log | tail` after logout and querying request described above:

```
2014/10/03 07:34:46 [error] 20657#0: *296 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) 
while connecting to upstream, client: 176.100.173.177, server: localhost, request: "GET 
/settler/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3031", host: "myhost.com:8081",   
referrer:  "http://myhost.com/settlersmain/"

2014/10/03 07:56:55 [error] 20657#0: *335 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) 
while connecting to upstream, client: 176.100.173.177, server: localhost, request: 
"GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3031", host: "myhost.com:8081"
2014/10/03 08:23:33 [error] 20657#0: *367 open()
```

Thanks for any help!

**UPD:** I replace `localhost` in `server_name` line of `nginx.conf` with server IP address, but issue is still present.

Comment: Are you sshing with a different user, `root` perhaps?

Comment: Try to enable `debug=True` in django project, so you'll see error details in browser

Comment: @stalk, no error details, I have the same.

Comment: @Ngenator, same issue.

Comment: One issue i see is here: `SprRegion.objects.values('id').get(Q(id=request.GET['region']))` . `.get()` returns an object, which does not have a `values` property. You might need to use `filter` instead.

Comment: @karthikr thank you, I will change my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your log you have `(111: Connection refused)` error, and it means that uwsgi process is killed after you close ssh connection.

You can try [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625409/how-do-i-put-an-already-running-process-under-nohup) to use `nohup`.

uWSGI has an option to [daemonize](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html?highlight=daemonize#daemonize). This is a better way, uWSGI will handle detaching from console.

But I suggest you use something like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to run uWSGI. Or you can use your system's `init.d` scripts or [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: Daemonize is the way to go. If you can't explain a service dying, having it automatically restarted isn't the best course of action in my experience, but ymmv.

Comment: Daemonize will work if process is killed due to log out i.e. `setopt no_hup` does not work. But if it dies for another reason (some un-handled exception) it will continue dying in daemon mode. Try to setup uwsgi logging with `logto` and check what causes it to exit

Comment: @Igor, I use Upstart config which run uwsgi. Works fine, thank you.