# Is there a way to interrupt a shell command but continue the pipeline that contains it?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

Consider the following contrived command:

```
cat /dev/urandom | wc -c
```

If you run it, `cat` sits and spins forever. If the process is killed with `^C`, the whole pipeline will stop and `wc` will never show its count. In most cases, this is the desired and appropriate behavior.

Suppose I wanted to stop `cat` and still run `wc` -- in essence, count the number of characters that went through up until the process was killed. Is there a nice way to accomplish that without switching to another shell and running `kill <PID of cat>`?

Comment: I believe this answer addresses your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/625436/3108853

Answer (score 3):

You can stop job using `Ctrl+Z`:

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | wc -c
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 cat /dev/urandom | wc -c
$
```

Now you can get list of processes in stopped job and kill process leader (`cat`, as you suggested in your question):

```
$ jobs -l
[1]+ 32164 Stopped                 cat /dev/urandom
     32165
```

`jobs -lp` will output only id of a group leader:

```
$ jobs -lp
32164
```

You can kill it:

```
$ kill `jobs -lp`
```

and continue execution of `wc`:

```
$ fg
cat /dev/urandom | wc -c
71106560
```

Comment: Yeah, that's similar to how I was initially trying to do it. I'm curious to see if the shell doesn't have a shorter way to send a SIGTERM directly to the leader without affecting the rest of the pipe.