# Running a SQL query in the background using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to have a SQL query run on the servers even after I turn off my computer?

I heard from a coworker that there was and she wanted me to do that.  I believe she said it was called a "screen"?

Comment: Yup there is screen command in Linux , just type screen in terminal and then it will open a new terminal ( new screen ) then run your SQL command there and press Ctrl +d  then get disconnected from ssh it will still run in background u can check that again by loging to ssh and typing screen -r

Comment: What kind of query? Depending on server version and configuration, there are also EVENTs.

Comment: i tried to close it with ctrl+D but it didnt seem to work.

Comment: I think Uueerdo is right about [Events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html), but if your coworker asked you and knows about it, maybe ask her for more information. That sort of communication is good to have on the work floor, and also you don't risk building something different than she wants you to. There is no shame in not knowing or not understanding something, but hiding that fact can lead to wrong expectations and lots of stress and frustration.

Comment: `screen` is absolutely not required for this particular use case, but many beginners like to be able to create a session on a server and then be able to disconnect from it and reconnect to it again later if they wish. `tmux` is a somewhat more modern alternative. There are many existing questions about how to set this up; perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527629/how-does-screen-command-works-in-linux

Answer (score 17):

I'm going to assume you are ssh-ing to a server and you want to be able to shutdown you local workstation.

You can use `nohup` and background processes. Also useful to know the `-e` option for the mysql command.

So something like this:

```
nohup mysql <options> -u <user> -p <pass> -e 'Insert Query Here' &
```

- `nohup` is for 'no hang up' i.e. don't end the process when I
  disconnect.
- `mysql ...`The mysql command you usually run
  to connect, just add the -e option to run the query without opening a
  mysql session
- `&` starts the process in the background

I'm unsure about this BUT:
If you don't want to put your password in the command, run the command without the password, type `fg` the password prompt should come back, enter your password, `ctrl-z` will send the process back to the background, then you can disconnect.

Comment: best way is:
nohup mysql <options> -u <user> -p -e 'your sql statement here' > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: @ShahadatHossainKhan, Why is that better? Without the redirect any messages or errors go to nohup.out, so you can review if the query worked or failed.

Comment: in terms of silence run, but if you want to debug its not a good approach i agreed

Answer (score 16):

If you find you are experiencing issues using `nohup` with `mysql` – I found an alternative solution inspired by @dan08's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30226138/1914455) on this page, as well as @Node's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625436/1914455) about putting an already running process into the background from another question on SO.

---

I had found that when trying the suggestion of using `nohup mysql...` to 'background' a long-running `mysql` command, that the remote MySQL server I was attempting to connect to refused the connection. When running the same `mysql` command without prefixing it with `nohup`, the connection succeeded and the `mysql` command worked as expected.

As such I looked for alternative methods of achieving the same end-result of being able to run a long-running SQL command (or set of SQL commands) without concerns about the process terminating if I disconnected from the shell session or if a networking issue caused a disconnection from the remote server. This research led to the working solution proposed below:

1. Run your `mysql` command as though you would like to run it in the foreground; for example: `mysql <options> -h <host> -u <user> -p -e "source
   /absolute/path/to/commands.sql" <database name> 2>&1 >
   ./mysql_output.log`
2. When asked, input the relevant password at the MySQL command prompt for the specified `<user>` (this is triggered by the inclusion of the `-p` flag in the `mysql` command above).
3. Immediately press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the current process, in this case `mysql`.
4. Run the `bg` command to move the currently suspended process into the background, and resume its processing.
5. Run the `jobs` command to list the jobs currently running in the shell session (you may only have one job listed if you don't have any other background processes running in the current session). From this list note the job number for `mysql`, which will likely be `1` if you only have one job running.
6. Last, but not least, run the `disown -h %<job number>` command, thus `disown -h %1` (assuming the job number obtained in step #5 above was `1`). This last command is very important, as it disassociates the current shell session from our `mysql` process which we have just moved into the background, so that the `mysql` process does not get killed when the terminal shell session ends. Without the call to `disown`, your `mysql` process that is now running in the background could still get killed if your terminal session ends.

The above sequence of commands effectively mimics a call to `nohup mysql...` by allowing you to move a long-running call to `mysql` into the background and not have the process terminated if you close your terminal session or get disconnected from the remote server. If you find that running `nohup mysql...` works in your circumstances that is great as it is certainly the easier and quicker approach, but at least in our application/server environment, we were unable to use `nohup mysql...` successfully.

The above sequence should also give you more control over executing the `mysql` command as you are initially running the command in the foreground; for instance running `mysql` in the foreground will allow you to enter your MySQL connection password securely at the MySQL prompt without having to provide the password as plain-text on the command line (which may be an important security consideration in some hosting/server environments, especially shared hosting where passwords entered on the command line would likely end up in log files such as ~/.bash_history or similar). Additionally, running the command in the foreground, will allow you to see and respond to any connection or other errors before the MySQL command gets moved into the background.

Credit must also go @dan08's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30226138/1914455) on this page, and to @Node for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625436/1914455) regarding placing an already running foreground process into the background, for helping inspire the solution proposed here.

Hopefully this proposed solution will help others who find themselves in a similar situation, where running `nohup mysql...` does not work as expected.

Comment: really nice breakout of the details! clear, thorough and informative!

Answer (score 8):

I prefer this way:

```
mysql -u <user> -p<pass> -e 'Insert Query Here' &>> query.log & disown
```

Example:

```
mysql -u root -pmypassword -e 'UPDATE bigtable SET column = "value";' &>> query.log & disown
```

- no space after `-p`
- `&>> query.log` redirects both stdout and stderr into `query.log` (use your path), otherwise entire output will be translated into terminal
- `&` runs the command in background
- `disown` detaches the command from current terminal, if you close the terminal then command won't die after timeout

You can control the command using

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

Also you can stop it using

```
KILL [id]; -- get the ID from previous command
```

Answer (score 3):

```
nohup mysql -h [host_ip_addr] -u [username] -p[password] [database_name] -e "sql_query" &
```

Note : don't give space after -p

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way...

1. Create such environment that will NOT prompt password when try to login mysql client. Make sure that you can logged in your database just typing "mysql" without user and password from your terminal.
2. Then use this command -

   nohup sh -c "mysql -e 'ALTER TABLE YourDatabaseName.TableName ADD anyColumnYouWantToAdd VARCHAR(50) NULL AFTER anyOldColumn'" > /dev/null 2>&1 &

NOTE: You must provide database name otherwise you have to put "use database" command also. Another issue may arise if you use column, table or database name with quote.

If you want to see log just use log file instead of "/dev/null"