# How does screen command works in Linux

Tags: linux

If a do screen in linux, and then ssh into some other machine, run a job there, detach from screen and disconnect the terminal. If i open the terminal again i can go that session and job is still running. I just want to know how internally this screen is working?

Comment: The `screen` utility has a "client server architecture". The server part is not terminated, only the client detaches. That way all child processes started by the server part stay intact and continue. And the client can reattach.

Comment: I may me mistaken, but it seems to me that what you want to do is the opposite: first connect to the other machine, there start a screen session, do some work in there, detach from it, close the ssh connection. When you connect again, you can re-attach to it. That's the usual use-case anyway. The way you do it, screen (on your machine) just keeps the ssh connection running, but it wouldn't survive a reboot of your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Detach does exactly what literally means.
It detaches the screen process from it's parent.
It means that his parent (your ssh session) will not inform his dependent/child process about its termination.

For more info this links could be useful:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup
>
> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and

Answer (score 0):

After ssh and successful login use **screen -S screen_name** to generate screen, then new tab will open. Run your program and you may close it. To see your program running use: **screen -r screen_name**.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question posted except being about `screen` utility.