# Start a job that does not end when my terminal session does?

Tags: unix, shell

How can I start a job on a *nix system that will not exit when my session exits?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command `nohup`, and then add an ampersand (&) at the end to put the job in the background.

```
$ nohup ./fetch_command > fetch_log_file &
```

Then you can exit the shell and the job will continue running.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should have known that.

Answer (score 2):

[nohup](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm) your_process &