# How to use fork() to daemonize a child process independent of its parent?

Tags: c, fork

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Linux, how to prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client)

I have a **C** program which I access and interact with over terminal (usually from SSH on a linux box).  I have been trying to find the solution to the problem where after I close the terminal/logout, the process ends with it (the program basically asks for some options then goes about its business with no further interaction required so I would like to have it continue to run even after I logout of SSH).

There are ways in linux to avoid this such as 'screen', but I want to do it programatically with **C** without relying on installed packages such as screen- even if this means reinventing the wheel.

So far I understand `fork()` to be the standard trivial way to daemonize a process, so could anyone help me to finish the code that allows the above described process to happen?

Within parent:

```
 main()
{

//Do interactive stuff

signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN); //stops the parent waiting for the child process to end

if(fork())
 exit(0);
// and now the program continues in the child process
```

I can now logout of SSH which closes the original shell...and the child continues its work!

Within child:

```
//Continue with processing data/whatever the program does (no input/output to terminal required)
exit(0);
```

Comment: Read all answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client

Comment: Um, just use `nohup` when you run it? No forking required.

Comment: @ Brian, nohup will not let me interact with the program. Its a command line interaction.

Comment: @San, I want to achieve the same aim without relying on nohup being installed.

Comment: See the suggested thread: answer #2 proposes to use the GNU Screen utility, that allows you to reconnect to a given "virtual terminal" across shell sessions.

Comment: @User That's somewhat similar to saying you want to program on Linux in C and not use any POSIX facilities.

Comment: @User I just tested... My Busybox device beside me has nohup...

Comment: So your question is that you don't know how to use `fork()`? What specific problem are you having?

Comment: @ san, point taken, but doesn't change my mind about doing this programatically.

Comment: @ Brian, the exitting of SSH/shell closes the parent and child still.

Comment: @User Fair enough. I won't argue the point anymore but I am curious over the use case where you can't rely on such a standard utility. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ San, thank you, and of course. In all honesty I would just like to carry out the task with usage: ./program.  Its sheer stuborness on my part I have to admit to rely on outside programs, even if these are standard in the very vast majority of linux installations.

Comment: Pretty annoying that this is closed as a duplicate, when the duplicate is clearly about shell usage, and this is about C programming.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**to detach the process from the parent**:

use setsid() on the children process, it will run the program in new session

```
 sid = setsid();
```

---

**To Keep a program running even when the terminal is closed**:

SIGHUP is a signal sent to a process when its controlling terminal is closed.

try to ignore it using

```
signal (SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
```

Comment: Yes others have suggested launching program with nohup- but can you suggest how to do this programatically within the context of the code I have posted?

Comment: @User you can install a signal hander for this signal that ignores it. just be sure to register the handler with the new process, not the parent.  http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Handling.html

Comment: you don't need signal (SIGHUP, SIG_IGN); because the parent exits and therefore the child will not have a controlling process