# How to keep rails command from Rails Console running after SSH Client (PuTTy) closes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, solr, putty, sunspot-solr

I connect to our Ubuntu production server using PuTTy.

I want to reindex a specific Model using Solr. I want to run the reindex command from the Rails Console, i.e. Modelname.reindex (as this seems to run quicker than the rake task.)

We are, however, looking at a vast volume of data and this indexing is expected to take a few hours.

I want to be able to start this task in the rails console and it should continue running even if I exit PuTTy. How to do this?

[Linux: Prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client) suggests nohup, but I don't see if/how that can be used with the rails console.

Comment: Could anyone point me to figure out why nohup doesn't work like we'd expect it to for a console application like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `sudo apt-get install screen` to install `screen`. Then run it using `screen`. Now you have a separate console window which can be detached using `Ctrl + A`, then `D`. Closing putty will not end your `screen`-session. If you log back in at any later point, you may resume the sessions using `screen -r`.

To summarize:

```
> sudo apt-get install screen
> screen
# pops up a new shell
> rails c
# run your reindex operation
# press Ctrl + A, then D
> exit
# putty closes

# reconnect using putty
> screen -r
# you should be back in your rails console
```

Comment: Enough good words could not be said about `screen`. Take a look at the `man screen` when you have a sec and see all the things you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use [screen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) to keep your session open on the server.

If you simply type `screen` a terminal multiplexer will start that will keep the session even if you disconnect your console.

Once you reconnect to the console you can get the session back using `screen -dr`

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like tmux or screen and detach from the session.