# How to start process via SSH, so it keeps running?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, sh, bitnami

I have three files:
monitor.sh, which starts python scripts:

```
sudo python ./webCheck &
sudo python ./apiCheck &
```

and the otherones, webCheck & apiCheck: it is supposed to run in the background, after I close the terminal. It checks my other website's availability, in an endless loop.

I can't get it to work, I am trying nohup, but can't get the syntax right. webCheck have to be run with sudo. Does nohup be included also in the sh script? I guess as the monitor.sh is just supposed to start other two, so that one doesn't need nohup.

How to do it?

Comment: I don't think there is anything particular to ec2 in this question, so I would check [Prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](http://stackoverflow.com/q/285015/950912)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use:

`sudo nohup python ./webCheck &`

`sudo nohup python ./apiCheck &`

I don't think your monitor.sh will need it, since it should take a relatively short time to start the other two.  However I'm not positive if the two checks would become children of monitor.sh, which may end up being an issue.

Comment: Works, I can kill the terminal and it still runs. It didn't show up after using sudo ps, but when I do sudo ps aux | less, it shows up!

Comment: Glad it worked!  You may also want to look at nneonneo's recommendation.  Daemonizing the program could be a better solution, depending on what you're trying to do.