# Keep SSH session alive

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I use `ssh -p8520 username@remote_host` to login remote server.

**Issue**:

It is always connected and works properly when I am in the work place. Unfortunately, terminal freezes in 10 - 15 minutes after I connected with the remote server from home.

There's no error/timeout report on the console but the cursor cannot move any more.

When enter <kbd>w</kbd> to check the login users, some zombies login users are there, and I have to kill them manually.

This is quite annoying. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have had this too, I started to use `screen`. Maybe this is some kind of a timeout issue.

Comment: @martin `screen` helps to keep the program running. Unfortunately sometimes i have to work on the remote server:(

Comment: If you start it without parameters, this gives you a shell.

Comment: Are your saying `screen` only? It can solve the lost connection issue?   No `screen -S screenName`?  I always use screen with `-S` and `-r`

Comment: No, this does not solve the issue, you only avoid loosing your work in the terminal. If you don't do anything, it will still freeze, you just can pick up where you started. I meant that you can create a terminal which you can always resume by using `screen`. You seem to already know that ;)

Comment: Related question: [How do I close a frozen SSH session? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981112/how-do-i-close-a-frozen-ssh-session) ■ Same question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/37738/577463) and [UNIX&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/200239/296692)

Answer (score 772, accepted):

The ssh daemon (sshd), which runs server-side, closes the connection from the server-side if the client goes silent (i.e., does not send information). To prevent connection loss, instruct the ssh client to send a sign-of-life signal to the server once in a while.

The configuration for this is in the file `$HOME/.ssh/config`, create the file if it does not exist (the config file must not be world-readable, so run `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config` after creating the file). To send the signal every e.g. four minutes (240 seconds) to the remote host, put the following in that configuration file:

```
Host remotehost
    HostName remotehost.com
    ServerAliveInterval 240
```

To enable sending a keep-alive signal for all hosts, place the following contents in the configuration file:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 240
```

Comment: The config must only be user-writable. readability is not a concern. Using 600 as your permission level is fine since that is only user-writable.

Comment: just in case it's not obvious this config file is on your PC/linux box

Comment: I always get confused about the config name: the client uses `ServerAliveInterval ` while the server uses `ClientAliveInterval `. What a mess.

Comment: @youkaichao There is often this confusion. As an API designer, there are reasons that I might put it in both ways. Ultimately, what's most critical, is good documentation of the chosen standard.

Comment: `c:/users/youruser/.ssh/config` for Windows

Comment: @youkaichao It's like if you went to Carl's house and you saw "Mike's address: <address>" on a slip of paper on the fridge. It's not confused that Mike's name is written in Carl's house; Carl is the only name that _doesn't_ need to appear at Carl's house.

Comment: I need this whenever using an AT&T cellular hotpot... they like to kill TCP connections every 5 minutes for fun.

Comment: why "must" we use chmod 600? what is so bad with default 644 permissions?

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui 644 allow group and public to read your config file, possibly leaking info. The manpage for ssh_config specify "read/write for the user, and not writable by others", which imply 644 is fine. But generally its safer to use 600 since 644 can trigger error in some circumstances.

Answer (score 310):

I wanted a one-time solution:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 myname@myhost.com
```

Stored it in an alias:

```
alias sshprod='ssh -v -o ServerAliveInterval=60 myname@myhost.com'
```

Now can connect like this:

```
me@MyMachine:~$ sshprod
```

Comment: That's cool, but not exactly a "one-time solution". If you're going to connect to the server more than once, why not do `Host *` & `ServerAliveInterval 240` (or specify the hostname, if you only want it for `myname@myhost.com` as in rockymonkey555's answer? Setting an alias doesn't seem easier in any way.

Comment: Or, just create an alias in your ~/.bashrc: `alias ssh='ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60'`

Comment: He means "one time" as in "it only works one time", not "I only have to write it one time".

Comment: Yes, if you read "one time" as "single use", this does the job perfectly.

Comment: If you want a "one-liner" that sets `ServerAliveInterval` to `60`, great. However using a bash alias when you could be using `.ssh/config` is just silly.

Comment: This works great when connecting to dev / production servers that have non-standard ports, to prevent having to type the port out every time -- Just make a separated alias per server/port EG `alias sshweb='ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 zak@example.com -p 9999'` OR  `alias sshdev='ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 zak@dev.example.com -p 7777'`

Comment: @CameronTacklind it's really not. Being an admin of a mixed estate means you have new IPs getting introduced every x minutes and old ones removed at a similar rate. Updating config each time - THAT is just silly. Especially when the domain names are nto guaranteed and IPs have no pattern suggesting which connections might be flaky (and/or likely to recover) and which ones will be reliable. I like to choose on-the-go when I want to try the conn with KA enabled and when not. So an alias is a perfectly useful option.

Comment: @netikras I don't see how aliases help with IP addresses changing. If you want to use an alias, go for it. I'd personally rather just use the tool's built-in configuration options instead of re-inventing my own.

Comment: this is a substandard solution for you. it only makes sense if you are creating a script that will be ran by other users. for your user you should create a host entry in the ssh config file. this will be honored for all your connections to this particular host, no matter what caused them. your solution breaks if you access the remote machine via sftp, xpra, etc... it might also break if your command is not ran in the usual environment, for example as a result of a GUI tool you did not launch from the shell. for your case, this is the wrong solution.

Answer (score 85):

For those wondering, @edward-coast

If you want to set the keep alive [for the server](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)), add this to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 2
```

> **ClientAliveInterval**: Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the client, sshd(8) will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the client.
>
> **ClientAliveCountMax**: 
>   Sets the number of client alive messages (see below) which may be sent without sshd(8) receiving any messages back from the client. If  this threshold is reached while client alive messages are being sent, sshd will disconnect the client, terminating the session.

Comment: It seems that there is no such "parameter" as ClientAliveInterval, only ServerAliveInterval, you can check in the manual page "man ssh_config"

Comment: That is the wrong one, look in "man sshd_config" for the server portion running the ssh daemon, not the client config.

Comment: Should I use `ClientAliveInterval` to let the server check for client alive, or should i let the client "ping" the server  with `ServerAliveInterval` repeatedly? Both seems not to make sense

Comment: Only set the `ClientAliveInterval` on the server if you want the server to disconnect on dead connections that do not respond, and you can customize how often and when that happens.

Comment: In my case, server side set `ClientAliveInterval 15` and `ClientAliveCountMax 2` , and client side set `-o reconnect` , works well when transferring large file through sshfs without stuck.

Answer (score 38):

[image: putty settings]

FYI Putty Users can set the options here

Answer (score 17):

We can keep our ssh connection alive by having following Global configurations

Add the following line to the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Comment: Does that only work for the client or does it also work for sshd?

Comment: @EdwardCoast It works on Client machine. I tested it on Mac