# How do I close a frozen SSH session?

Tags: ssh

Sometimes an SSH session to a remote server will freeze indefinitely due to bad internet connectivity. Is it possible to close the session without closing the terminal?

Comment: Same question on [UNIX&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2919/296692) and [Apple.SE (AskDifferent)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/35524/511124). ■ Related question: [linux - Keep SSH session alive - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25084288/5267751)

Answer (score 156):

Press the following three keys:

1. Enter
2. ~ (tilde)
3. . (period)

This is the "disconnect" function as described in the `ESCAPE CHARACTERS` section of the `ssh` `man` page.

Answer (score 62):

In [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/29952/453654), [geekosaur](https://askubuntu.com/users/11775/geekosaur) suggests we use the escape sequences as follows: "To kill the current session hit subsequently <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>.

More of these escape sequences can be listed with <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>?</kbd>:

```
Supported escape sequences:
  ~.  - terminate session
  ~B  - send a BREAK to the remote system
  ~R  - Request rekey (SSH protocol 2 only)
  ~#  - list forwarded connections
  ~?  - this message
  ~~  - send the escape character by typing it twice
(Note that escapes are only recognized immediately after newline.)
```

You can close the list of Escape sequences by hitting <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>.

Notice that because hitting <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> causes `ssh` to send the `~` instead of intercepting it, you can address *N* nested `ssh` connections by hitting <kbd>~</kbd> *N* times. (This only applies to <kbd>~</kbd>s that directly follow an <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>.) That is to say that <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> terminates an `ssh` session 5 layers deep and keeps the other 4 intact."