# Break out of frozen/hung AWS CLI SSM session

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-ssm

If you have an open interactive session to an AWS instance or container eg started with

```
aws ecs execute-command --cluster testCluster --task XXXsomeTaskIdXXX --interactive --command "/bin/sh"
```

You will receive a command prompt. If the session hangs for some reason e.g. intermittent network, is there a way to force the session to close? i.e. the equivalent of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43189095/4653517 for SSH

If you wait it seems like the session is eventually timed out.

Comment: Do you want to close the session or stop the command from running?

Comment: If by command you mean the local command then I would like it to exit and return me to my local prompt. "normal" approaches CTRL+D, CTRL+C, are captured so do not work, therefore I assume as in the SSH case there is a "special" sequence to use?

Comment: Opened an issue https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/7488 for this

Answer (score 0):

**CTRL + C** seems to work fine for me

(macOS, iterm)