# Keep SSH Sessions running after disconnection

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I am using my laptop via shell terminal to log on school’s server to run a
Matlab session. The session will take about 10 hours and I want to close my
laptop, go home, have dinner, and re-engage the shell terminal to check the
progress of my Matlab session.

From [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479) I know I should use nohup `nohup` to keep my terminal alive,
but I meet the following problem. Here is a screenshot of my shell after I start
running Matlab session:

> [image: my matlab session]

where `a = cv000_29590` is the respond from the Matlab. It should keep running
until `cv999999` and take about 10 hours.

The problem is, this shell is not interactive anymore. I can’t enter anymore
commands, that is, I have no where to enter `nohup` commend to keep my SSH
session alive.

Comment: `GNU Screen` or `tmux`

Comment: Run `screen` then start your process. Press ctrl+a, ctrl+d, then log off. Later, log on and enter `screen -r`.

Comment: @ChrisLear awesome!!! Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep SSH session alive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25084288/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really possible after you've already started a session. But for new sessions you can do the following:

1. Add the following to the top of your `.bash_profile`:

   ```
   if [ -z "${PS1}" ] ; then
       return
   fi

   if [ "${TERM}" != "screen" ] ; then
       export HOSTNAME
       exec screen -xRR
   fi

   function new {
       u=${1:-$USER}
       test ${u} = ${USER} && screen -t ${u}@${HOSTNAME} || screen -t ${u}@${HOSTNAME} su --login ${u}
   }
   ```
2. Put the following content into `.screenrc`:

   ```
   escape ^bb
   shell -$SHELL
   termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@
   hardstatus lastline "%-Lw[%n%f %t]%+Lw%<"
   screen -t ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}
   ```

   These are mostly my own customizations of screen. The most important of which is that I set the screen escape character to `CTRL-b` instead of the default `CTRL-a` so I can still use `CTRL-a` in bash to go to the beginning of a line.
3. Use `CTRL-b c` to create shells in new windows (or just type `new` at the bash prompt to use the function). And use `CTRL-b d` to detach your session and leave it running. Next time you login, you'll be reattached to your session and everything will be as it was. Use `CTRL-b n` to cycle through the windows you've created. If you don't want to multiple windows, you don't have to, just use the ability to leave a session running and reattach later.