# Keep SSH Sessions running after disconnection - for overnight

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

This is a follow up question for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041892/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection).

I took the advise by @Chris Lear by using `screen` commend. It works great, for short time sign out. But i met the following question several times.

After I log out, by ctrl+a, ctrl+d, and go to sleep, and try to resume on next morning, I am keep getting the following error message and the matlab progress on server is dead.

The error message is:
packet_write_wait: connection to 128.2.xx.xxx: Broken pipe.

any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Is matlab sending data back to your laptop directly? You are sshing in to the remote machine and then running matlab there correct?

Comment: Yes. and when I log on, the matlab sending back data to my laptop directly.

Comment: In which order are you executing the commands ssh, screen, matlab when you log in for the first time?

Comment: Simply log in to the server again and call `screen -d -r`

Comment: @ChristophSommer start terminal, screen, ssh, matlab. For log out, ctrl+a, ctrl+d, for resume, screen -r

Comment: @tankonetoone: screen should work. It sounds like your problem is that the matlab on the server is initiating a connection back to your laptop, then you are switching off your laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the screen on the server (as opposed to on the client, which is what you seem to be doing right now). This way, MATLAB can write output even if you are not connected to the server via ssh. The order of commands for this is ssh, screen, matlab. If you want to resume your session, just connect to the server via ssh, then run something like screen -x

Comment: Good idea! I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Open `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on your (client) computer. Add the following line:

```
ServerAliveInterval 100
ServerAliveCountMax 3  (default)
```

You can also set these values at the *per-user* level in `~/.ssh/config`

Just remember this -- if you leave your ssh session open accidentally, anyone else with access to your desktop can get on it. Remember to close your session when finished.

Comment: My terminal says: Permission denied...

Comment: As long as you are using `openSSH` it shouldn't matter if you are on a mac or PC. You will need root access to set the system-wide default `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` values, use `~/.ssh/config` for yourself only. (if that is where your per-user `.ssh` dir is stored on the mac, otherwise set them where that may be.)