# Running Python Script on Remote Server via SSH

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I am trying to run this Python Script on a Digital Ocean (DO) Droplet (Ubuntu 16):
https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py

Although I can run `python3 example.py` the process stops if I kill the Terminal windown I used to SSH into the DO Droplet.

Is there a way to run this Python script and disconnect from the DO Droplet with the Python script still running?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep SSH Sessions running after disconnection - for overnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205456/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection-for-overnight)

Answer (score 4):

Use `nohup` to run program in background

```
nohup python3 example.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Or you can use `screen` to do this:

```
$ screen
$ python3 example.py
To detach the current session, you can press Ctrl+A and then press D.
To re-attach previous session, use command `screen -r`
```

The `screen` command is more powerful than `nohup`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `screen` in linux to continue executing the process in background even after you disconnect from server.
Similarly `tmux` can be used.

The answer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480/182017) question is most probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these python library to achieve this

http://www.paramiko.org/

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spur

Or you can also use tmux to run command on remote server and your tmux seisson will run in the background even if you quit the shell. You can join that tmux session even after days and continue executing command

Answer (score 0):

We use the following format to execute remote script
`ssh -t -t user@host.com 'nohup /path/to/scrip.py'`