# Ubuntu 14 freezes on "save as", "open" dialog when is connected to server on nautilus

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Hello. When a server is connected through the nautilus option "file / connect to server", after some minutes, the connection is "frozen". So, nautilus does not respond, and any other dialog option from what ever other application, like "open" or "save as" dialog, is hanged up.
The opened applications are greyed and never responds.

I've realized that if there is no exists any connection to the server through nautilus, then it does not occur. It only happens when some connection to server is created on nautilus and spend a few minutes.

I've tryed to keep alive ssh session as https://stackoverflow.com/a/25087194/2501648 but with no success. I dont know if I am doing some wrong or whether using .ssh/config from my computer to set the KeepAlive parameter has sense.

My servers connections with nautilus are through SSH and I suspect that the key is send any packets each some time to keep alive the connection, but I don't know how to make it.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll thanks to @campovski for his recomendations.
The problem was origin by the new router, which dropped TCP connections with no use for a while.
So, despite the @campovski recommendations, the only way it worked for me was edit on the client:

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and append at the end of the file:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Answer (score 1):

What is causing this is your unresponsiveness for few minutes. I won't tell you exactly what to do but will guide you to real answer. Take a look at `ServerAliveInterval`. You set this on client. If you want to set a keep-alive on server, take a look at `ClientAliveInterval`. Both values are set in `$HOME/.ssh/config` (of course one on client, the other on server; no need for both!).