# How to SET and KEEP remote connection with database by Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, ssh

I look for solution in my Laravel application. 
I have database on another server and try co connect it with my app.
I am not sure how to set .env file and how to set and keep connection between servers.

I read about approach with ssh connection:

```
ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 myuser@remotehost.com
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u dbuser -p db
```

and that works but after one day connection expires and again I have to set the connection on server. I need to keep it.

Do you have solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084288/keep-ssh-session-alive

Comment: I read and tried that, but how can I check does it work? How to change server expiration of ssh connection?

Comment: Well, why don't you try playing with the expiration? First try 1 minute, does it work? Then 10 minutes etc.

Comment: I played a lot. Look, now by default I guess expiration is 12 hours, because connection works all day. After night it does not work. So i look for place to change it on apache. Do not where.

Comment: If this mysql is not public, why don't you just allow the IP address of your Laravel application to connect to it?

Comment: I receive: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused . I set DB_HOST=XXX.XXX.X.XX
DB_PORT=3306, maybe port is wrong but do not know how to check it