# How do I keep SSH connection alive on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, openssh, windows-shell

I've added the `OpenSSH client (Beta)` feature on Windows 10 so I can call it by running

```
ssh
```

on the command line.

However the terminal windows (and thus the connection) freezes when inactive for too long. I know I would solve this on Linux by editing the `~/.ssh/config` file. Is there an equivalent on Windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep SSH session alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084288/keep-ssh-session-alive)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can solve this on the client side by setting the options ServerAliveInterval and ServerAliveCountMax (60 and 30 will send a keep-alive packet every minute and still keep the connection if your network falls for up to 30 minutes).

The Windows OpenSSH client has some issues finding the ssh_config file (it appears to have doubts about what the "home" directory is in a Windows System), so you may have to explicitly provide the config file path with -F:

```
ssh -F C:\wherever\ssh_config user@host
```

On the server side you can edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config, edit/add the similar ClientAliveInterval and ClientAliveMaxCount options and restart the sshd service.

Comment: You're right @FBergo - Windows tricky to get it to take effect and annoying to keep restarting terminal window. This hits the problem right on the head - works nicely.

Answer (score 59):

In `C:\Users\yourusername\.ssh` make a new file named `config`, and add the lines below:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 40
```