# Resume gdb session after parent shell terminated

Tags: linux, bash, debugging, gdb, disconnection

I was running gdb over an SSH shell. After a while the shell disconnected due to being idle. On reconnecting I see the gdb instance still running.

1. How do I take control of the running gdb instance?
2. Can I start a new gdb instance and take over the session from the running gdb instance?

Note: This is not about keeping the SSH session alive. This is more about taking control of gdb from another shell instance. Regardless of whether it is running from SSH or locally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep SSH session alive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25084288/608639), [Keep SSH Sessions running after disconnection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479/56041), [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/q/8653), [How to detach ssh session without killing a running process?](https://superuser.com/q/1293298/173513), [Resume command running in dropped SSH session](https://serverfault.com/q/115998/145545), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't do anything with the gdb that is already running.  It probably no longer has a controlling tty at all.  What you probably want to do is kill it and then start a new gdb process, but do it inside a program like **tmux** or **screen**.  If you do that, then if/when you get disconnected you can easily reattach to the tmux/screen session any time.  Just check out the manual for those programs.  They do pretty much the same thing.  I think tmux is a little more powerful.

Comment: Thanks Bob. Any idea what decides whether or not a process terminates when SSH terminates?

Comment: It should get a signal.  SIGHUP I believe.  It all depends on how the program handles that signal.

Comment: tmux/screen won't exit, though.  you can just reattach when you reconnect.  There are also some ways to prevent ssh from disconnecting at all, assuming the connection itself is reliable.  Somewhere along the line I set ServerAliveInterval in ssh_config for a server that was behaving that way.  I prefer that my ssh sessions stay connected even when nothing is happening in them...