# MongoDB compass gets disconnected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-compass

Im working on an application with node and mongodb for the first time. I user mongodb compass to access the database. The issue im having is, it gets disconnected when it is not active for about 30 minutes or more. How can I solve this issue? Is there any configuration that I should use to avoid this? I'm using mongodb for the first time.

```
Server selection timed out after 10000 ms
```

This is the error I get when it is disconnected.

Comment: Are you connecting to MongoDB instance through SSH config?
If yes then you need some extra configuration to make ssh connection to keep alive 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25087194/3236733