# Default expiration time of SSH keys generated by Compute Engine for OS Login

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to understand more on the OSLogin feature. If I launch a SSH session with OSLogin, what is the default expiration time given to the SSH KEY generated by Compute Engine. And once that expires, will the existing SSH session gets terminated forcefully? Or is there any option to extend the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the concepts of OS Login is to simplify key management [1]. Key management is automatic, if you have the correct permissions and you try to connect to an instance, a key will be generated for you if you do not have a key already. Although you can choose to manage your keys manually [2].

To answer your question even if the SSH key generated by OS Login expires, your session will not terminate. Normally you would get an error when trying to start an SSH session after the key expired. With OS Login you won’t have any error because a new key will be generated for you.

If you want to keep an SSH session running for a long time and avoid idle timeouts I recommend checking this answer [3].

I checked my auto-created SSH keys for OS Login and the normal ones for Compute Engine, they do not seem to have an expiration date.

Refer to this part of the document to add your existing SSH key to Compute Engine [4] I recommend you use the console method for this one.

To create a new key refer to this part [5]

Basically run this in your Linux machine or in Cloud Shell:

ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME] -C [USERNAME]

Then make the private key read only:

chmod 400 ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#add_oslogin_keys

[3] https://stackoverflow.com/a/25087194/12852097

[4] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide

[5] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys

Comment: Hi Erhard, thanks for response. I was specifically looking for what the expiration time is when Compute engine is adding public key to the Google account. When I checked get profile, I think I saw that the value is coming as 0. Does that mean it never expires?

Comment: Also, if I want to push my own public key, can you please give me a sample of the format?

Comment: I tried ssh-rsa keyvalue account name. But it didn't work

Comment: Hi Nagesh, I edited my answer. Yes, 0 means no expiration date.

Comment: Hey Erhard, Thanks a lot the info. What I observed during testing is that : If I create my ssh key pair, I'm able to push the public key with osloginapi and a Linux profile (username, home directory, uid, gid, etc) is getting created. However when I push key using directory API (I used Google's own TRY API feature), it doesn't create OSLogin profile. So, not able to ssh to a fresh instance where I never logged in using console/gcloud. Any idea what might be missing here?

Comment: Hi Nagesh, I have no clue what's the issue in your case. I deleted my OSLogin profile and it gets recreated when I add a key. I used gcloud commands to do this which also calls the API. The command I used was 'gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add'.

Comment: Hi Erhard, it works fine with gcloud and console. Issue is with Directory API. For some reason, it only adds the ssh key but not creating Linux profile.

Comment: Hello Nagesh, I tried it with the Directory API and it created a profile for me. Can you post some screenshots showing the process? You can send it privately if you would like to. Just make sure to hide sensitive information like project name etc.

Comment: Hey Erhard. Sorry for the late response. I got tied up. So, I was trying that for a poc and don't have details now. I will have to redo the poc for details. But I was trying using the Google apis in the browser where there is that "try it" option available. When you tried with Directory API, did you use sdk? Or tried in browser?

Comment: Hi Nagesh, I used the SDK since I am more used to console commands.

Comment: Ah! Ok. Thanks a lot Erhard. So, probably the TRY API doesn't have that support yet. When I used that, in the inputs section the option to select those inputs were not present. I still went ahead and added them manually. It used to add the keys to the profile but it never created them on the Linux instances or that profile update. I will try with sdk. Thanks a lot, again! Appreciate your prompt responses.