# SSH connection keep disconnecting when idle

Tags: ssh, disconnect, disconnected-session

When the ssh connection is idle I get `client_loop: send disconnect: Boken pipe` what can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep SSH session alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084288/keep-ssh-session-alive)

Answer (score 1):

Create/edit the file ~/.ssh/config in your local computer.
In the file paste the following and save.

```
Host *
 UseKeychain yes
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 ForwardAgent yes
 ServerAliveInterval 60
 ServerAliveCountMax 2
```

This will send keep-alive to the connected server and will not disconnect due to inactivity.